# a/an substitution in LaTeX

Tags: conditionals

I was wondering if there is a conditional command that I can use in LaTeX (e.g., `\ifthenelse`) that would allow me to, in one case, use the word 'a' and in another use the word 'an' based on the whether or not the following word starts with a vowel.

Comment: Check out this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332/575.  In particular, I'd say the answer is "no".  There are several packages (`ifthen`, `etoolbox`, maybe others) which provide general conditional commands; TeX itself has many, but they are hard to understand.  Search the questions on this site for more than one that ask about these.

Comment: This is more complicated than just checking for consonant/vowel, as the the selection of a/an is [phonetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_and_an#Discrimination_between_a_and_an).

Comment: Caramdir's quite right, don't do that: A unicorn, an ugly unicorn, a horse, an hour.

Comment: Exact duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4233707/505649

Comment: People even disagree over "a" or "an" hotel, which apparently depends on your pronounciation of the 'h'...

Comment: @Ulrich: Just for completeness, could you copy your solution here. After all, it does solve the posed question and I doubt there is a shorter solution.

Comment: @Caramdir: can do. It seems to work for me, even if it doesn't appear to do so for @Raffi Khatchadourian.

Comment: @Ulrich: works for me too.

Comment: @Ulrich: I think you want to use `\if` not `\ifx` there. You wouldn't need the `\expandafter`.

Comment: Yes, I understand it's not a general solution, but it would work for the majority of cases I need it for, and also reduce the number of cases I need to edit my latex code. @Ulrich: It doesn't work for me, possible because I am using a command following \AOrAn. I commented about this in the other site.

Comment: Caramdir is right.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Caramdir that checking for a vowel is insufficient for determining which article to use. Nonetheless, if you really want to do this, this is how I will do this in ConTeXt.

```
\def\placearticle#1%
  {\doifinsetelse{#1}{a,e,i,o,u}{an}{a} #1}

% Alternative definition, but a bit slower
% \def\placearticle#1%
%   {\doifinstringelse{#1}{aeiou}{an}{a} #1}

\starttext
\placearticle apple,
\placearticle orange,
\placearticle banana,
\placearticle strawberry
\stoptext
```

I don't know which LaTeX package provides functionality similar to `\doifinsetelse` or `\doifinstringelse`.

Answer (score 2):

To do this in plain TeX (works in LaTeX too) I would say something like:

```
\newtoks\vowellist % make a new empty token register named vowellist
\vowellist{\\a\\e\\i\\o\\u} % put vowels in it delimited by \\
                            % Redefining \\ will allow us to map over the list.
\def\placearticle#1{
   \edef\tempa{#1}                % In case #1 is a command, fully expand it.
   \def\tempb#1#2.${\let\tempc#1} % make \tempc the first symbol of tempa
   \expandafter\tempb\tempa.$     %
   \def\\##1{\ifx\tempc##1 n\fi}  % Check if the current vowel is the same as the letter in \tempc
   a\the\vowellist\\
        % Map \\ over \vowellist 
   \tempa                      % Insert #1; use tempa to make sure #1 isn't evaluated twice.
}
```

This should work with any reasonably sane input, but I haven't te