# Create an array of variables

Tags: arrays

I'm creating a package for my question papers. (I'm aware of the exam class but I don't want to use that.) I have everything ready but I want to create a grading table at the top of the first page. For that, I need to put the exam points in an array. I have a command that is called for outputting the score. What I need to do is put them in some array-like variable so that I can then loop over it and output the points in a table. How can I create that array? I have no idea. Any hints would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I would think in terms of a list structure and possibly a table. Would http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19746/cunning-latex-tricks/19761#19761 form a basis of what you want? Can you define better what you mean by array like variable? I guess you mean a like a row in a table?

Comment: By now you probaly already have an answer that works for you, but this is what I did when I wanted to do the same in my exam template: https://bitbucket.org/mickesv/templates/overview (You'll find it in the ExamTemplate directory). I probably went overboard and wrote the question points into the .aux-file, and create the table on the next compile round, but the output is probably close to what you would like.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can define a macro which name contains numbers. Use LaTeX2e's `\@namedef` and `\@nameuse`, or `\csdef`, `\csuse` from `etoolbox` package. And `etoolbox` itself provides list operations without index.

An example:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{cnt}
\newcommand\textlist{}
\newcommand\settext[2]{%
  \csdef{text#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\addtext[1]{%
  \stepcounter{cnt}%
  \csdef{text\thecnt}{#1}}
\newcommand\gettext[1]{%
  \csuse{text#1}}

\newcounter{colnum}
\newcommand\maketabularrow[1]{%
  \setcounter{colnum}{0}%
  \whileboolexpr
    { test {\ifnumcomp{\value{colnum}}{<}{#1}} }%
    {&\stepcounter{colnum}\thecolnum}
  }

\begin{document}

\addtext{one}
\addtext{two}
\addtext{three}
\settext{100}{one hundred}

This is text \gettext{1} and \gettext{3}, that is text \gettext{2}.

\begin{tabular}{ |c@{} *{\thecnt}{c|} } % the first row is hidden
\hline
\maketabularrow{\thecnt}\\ \hline
\end{tabular}

100 is \gettext{100}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, try to do it inside a `tabular` environment!  (I did, and it won't work - and the results are, well, weird. I don't have time to examine this problem now, I guess it might be connected with expansion timing.)

Comment: @mbork: Indeed, expansion makes it difficult to make a tabular in a loop. You must design the `tabular` first and pass the list through argument. I'll add an example.

Comment: Interesting (and fairly complicated). I will try it out and post follow up comments.

Comment: @recluze: Yes, it is quite complicated if you want to make a `tabular` in a loop. However, it is much easier to put several tabulars (boxes) together — it looks like a single tabular.

Comment: @LeoLiu: thanks, I was thinking about something like that.  I guess it /might/ be done in a simpler way, but I'm not sure.  Also, I am pretty sure that a clean solution using luatex exists.

Comment: @mbork: Well, I was wrong. It does have a much easier solution. If I use `etoolbox` to get the loop, everything could be easier. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks. The example works really well. I had to modify it a little bit to suit my specific question but it's the same general idea. I'm posting my working example as an answer below for anyone interested.

Answer (score 10):

You have two questions that I can see.  First, you want to know how to create an associative (programming) array mapping questions to their points.  And second, you want to know how to create a (LaTeX table) array that prints these.  As I usually do, I recommend using `pgfkeys` as your programming language here, particularly (in this case) because as a key-value package, its entire life is devoted to constructing associative arrays.

Here's how I'd create your array of points:

```
\usepackage{pgfkeys}
\pgfkeys{
 /points array/.is family, /points array,
 .unknown/.style = {\pgfkeyscurrentname/.initial = #1},
}

\newcommand\questionhaspoints[1]{\pgfkeys{/points array, #1}}
\newcommand\getquestionpoints[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/points array/#1}}
```

You can then write, say, `\questionhaspoints{1 = 10, 2 = 5}` to say that question 1 has 10 points and question 2 has 5 points.  If you want to retrieve these, you just call `\getquestionpoints{1}` and `\getquestionpoints{2}`.

The `\pgfkeys` invocation sets up the family `/points array` so that any time you try to assign a new key in it (one that is "unknown" as of yet) it is simply filled with the value you requested.  `pgfkeys` can do lots of stuff with keys other than just store their values, as you will see in a second.

To construct the LaTeX array, I think it is necessary to loop and construct the rows before calling `\begin{tabular}`, since in TeX, alignments are very particular about what can appear where in them, in particular the `&` and `\\` directives.  It's best for everything to look "right" before starting the table.

Here is my code for constructing the table:

```
\usepackage{pgffor}
\pgfkeys{
 /points array,
 add to table/.style = {
  table/.append = {
   Question #1
   &
   \getquestionpoints{#1}
   \\
  },
 },
}

\newcommand\makepointstable[1]{%
 \pgfkeys{
  /points array,
  table/.initial = {},
  add to table/.list = {1,...,#1}
 }%
}
```

The new key `/points array/add to table` just tacks its argument onto a key called `table` (presumed to be in `/points array` too).  It is used in the loop that is implied by the construction `add to table/.list = {<list of question numbers>}`, which performs a loop over the numbers in its argument, calling `add to table` with that number each time.  The result is that the `table` key holds the body of the array.  Now you can put that in a `{tabular}`.  Here is a complete document that does that:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys,pgffor}

\pgfkeys{
 /points array/.is family, /points array,
 .unknown/.style = {\pgfkeyscurrentname/.initial = #1},
 add to table/.style = {
  table/.append = {
   Question #1
   &
   \getquestionpoints{#1}
   \\
  },
 },
}

\newcommand\questionhaspoints[1]{\pgfkeys{/points array, #1}}
\newcommand\getquestionpoints[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/points array/#1}}

\newcommand\makepointstable[1]{%
 \pgfkeys{
  /points array,
  table/.initial = {},
  add to table/.list = {1,...,#1}
 }%
}

\begin{document}
 \questionhaspoints{1 = 10, 2 = 8, 3 = 15, 4 = 10}
 \makepointstable{4}

 \begin{tabular}{l|r}
  \pgfkeysvalueof{/points array/table}
 \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

The latest version of etoolbox provides *lists* and their management options. Here is the solution for any one interested.

The below code demonstrates how easy it is now to create and iterate over a list of variables.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox} % defines lists and their operations
\RequirePackage{tabulary} % defines content-based sizable tables

\begin{document}

% define few variables that hold some value
\def\One{this is one}
\def\Two{this is two}
\def\Three{this is three}

% add the above commands to a list named `CmdList'
\listcsgadd{CmdList}{One}
\listcsgadd{CmdList}{Two}
\listcsgadd{CmdList}{Three}

% Now loop-over them to print their values
\begin{description}
    \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\item[#1:] \csuse{#1}}
    \dolistcsloop{CmdList}
\end{description}    

% creating a table needs little bit more trickery; You cannot insert table entries directly.
% You first have to accumulate all table data into some temporary variable and then use that.
\begingroup
    \newcommand\tablecontent{}
    \def\do#1{\appto\tablecontent{\hline \textbf{#1} & \csuse{#1}\\}}%
    \dolistcsloop{CmdList} % collect the data in a table format
    \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{|L|L|} % now print the collected data 
        \tablecontent \hline
    \end{tabulary}              
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

[image: List values in description and table format]

Answer (score 4):

With the [`spreadtab`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/spreadtab) package, you can set up a tabular environment that has some basic spreadsheet functionality. This should be enough to sum your exam points.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to this package - it looks promising!

Comment: Thanks for the package link. It's very interesting but I don't see how it will be relevant to my problem. My situation is simpler but different.

Comment: @recluze then I don't understand what you want. Could you add an example that shows how you would like things to work? What do you mean by a "grading table"?

Answer (score 3):

Working on the answer by Leo Liu above, here's what works for a grading table:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{cnt}
\newcommand\textlist{}
\newcommand\settext[2]{%
  \csdef{text#1}{#2}}
  \newcommand\addtext[1]{%
    \stepcounter{cnt}%
    \csdef{text\thecnt}{#1}}
    \newcommand\gettext[1]{%
      \csuse{text#1}}


      \begin{document}

        \addtext{3}
        \addtext{2}
        \addtext{4}


        This is text \gettext{1} and \gettext{3}, that is text \gettext{2}.


        \begin{tabular}{ |c@{} *{\thecnt}{c|} } % the first row is hidden
          \hline
           \newcounter{colnum}%
           \setcounter{colnum}{0}
           \whileboolexpr
           { test {\ifnumcomp{\value{colnum}}{<}{\thecnt}} }%
           {&\stepcounter{colnum}\gettext{\thecolnum}}\\
            \hline        
             \setcounter{colnum}{0}
             \whileboolexpr
             { test {\ifnumcomp{\value{colnum}}{<}{\thecnt}} }%
             {&\stepcounter{colnum}\hspace{1cm}}\\\hline
          \end{tabular}

      \end{document}
```

The output is this:

[image]