# Use csdef variables before defining them

Tags: macros

I'm trying to create a grade table. This is a follow up question to [Create an array of variables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37426/create-an-array-of-variables). The issue is that the grading table sits below the questions. The way I want is that the questions should appear after the grading table.However, if the grading table is at the top, I will have not called any `csdef` commands and I won't have any output. (I've tried and this is true, of course.) So, how can I put the grading table before the actual questions.

p.s. I've tried `totcount` package and replaced `csdef`s with `\newtotcounter` but it gives huge number of errors which I have no clue about.

My MWE is here:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{cnt}

\newcommand\addtext[1]{%
    \stepcounter{cnt}%
    \csdef{text\thecnt}{#1}}

\newcommand\gettext[1]{%
      \csuse{text#1}}

\begin{document}

Question 1: Blah. 
\addtext{3}

Question 2: Blah.
\addtext{2}

Question 3: Blah.
\addtext{4}     

\begin{tabular}{ |l|c@{} *{\thecnt}{c|} } % the first row is hidden
  \hline
  \newcounter{colnum}%
  \setcounter{colnum}{0}%
  Q. No.:\hfill & 
  \whileboolexpr
  { test {\ifnumcomp{\value{colnum}}{<}{\thecnt}} }%
      {&\stepcounter{colnum}\thecolnum}\\
  \hline
  Score: &         
      \setcounter{colnum}{0}
      \whileboolexpr
      { test {\ifnumcomp{\value{colnum}}{<}{\thecnt}} }%
      {&\stepcounter{colnum}\hspace{1cm}}\\
  \hline
  Total: & 
      \setcounter{colnum}{0}
      \whileboolexpr
      { test {\ifnumcomp{\value{colnum}}{<}{\thecnt}} }%
      {&\stepcounter{colnum}\gettext{\thecolnum}}\\
  \hline        
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could put the questions in `saveboxes` and then use these after the table. As far as I know you can't have paragraph constructs in a `savebox` though, so you would need one for every question. Perhaps there is an easier way?

Comment: There is, and TeX.SX found it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can abuse the `\label`-`\ref` mechanism: the `\addtext` macro defines `\@currentlabel` as the grade for the exercise and issues a `\label` command that `\gettext` will retrieve at the next run. At end document we store also the final number of exercises. In order to avoid problems when the `.aux` file hasn't yet the information, we set `\finalnumber` to 2 if `\getrefnumber{lastcnt}` returns 0.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{etoolbox,refcount}


\newcounter{cnt}
\AtEndDocument{\refstepcounter{cnt}\label{lastcnt}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\addtext[1]{%
    \stepcounter{cnt}%
    \def\@currentlabel{#1}%
    \label{text\thecnt}}
\makeatother

\newcommand\gettext[1]{\getrefnumber{text#1}}

\newcounter{colnum}

\begin{document}

\ifnum\getrefnumber{lastcnt}=0 
  \def\finalnumber{2}%
\else
  \edef\finalnumber{\number\numexpr\getrefnumber{lastcnt}-1\relax}%
\fi

\begin{tabular}{ |l|c@{} *{\finalnumber}{c|} } % the first row is hidden
  \hline
  \setcounter{colnum}{0}%
  Q. No.:\hfill & 
  \whileboolexpr
  { test {\ifnumcomp{\value{colnum}}{<}{\finalnumber}} }%
      {&\stepcounter{colnum}\thecolnum}\\
  \hline
  Score: &         
      \setcounter{colnum}{0}
      \whileboolexpr
      { test {\ifnumcomp{\value{colnum}}{<}{\finalnumber}} }%
      {&\stepcounter{colnum}\hspace{1cm}}\\
  \hline
  Total: & 
      \setcounter{colnum}{0}
      \whileboolexpr
      { test {\ifnumcomp{\value{colnum}}{<}{\finalnumber}} }%
      {&\stepcounter{colnum}\gettext{\thecolnum}}\\
  \hline        
\end{tabular}

Question 1: Blah. 
\addtext{3}

Question 2: Blah.
\addtext{2}

Question 3: Blah.
\addtext{4}     

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great. I don't understand the description right now but it works perfectly. I will study the run in detail to understand what you're saying. It's not your lack of clarity; it's my inexperience.