# Read command with varying input arguments

Tags: macros, parsing

Out of curiosity I'd like to define a LaTeX command that looks like:

`\newcommand{\trigger}{out1,out2,...,outn}`

with a rather strange function (at least, I couldn't find anything like this elsewhere):

First of all, the number of arguments `out1,out2,...` etc. are variables. Then, every time the `\trigger` command is used in the document's content, a different *string* is printed: first `out1`, then `out2`, etc. and finally `outn`. After `outn` is printed, the whole thing should be reset such that the next *string* will be `out1` again.

So the first problem I have is to make a command that can read the comma separated list between `{}` and the second problem is how to print just one them every time the newly defined command is called.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the earlier answers, but here's another one

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\triggerlist}{out1,out2,...,outn}
\def\trigger{\expandafter\xtrigger\triggerlist\xtrigger}
\def\xtrigger#1,#2\xtrigger{#1\def\triggerlist{#2,#1}}

\begin{document}

\trigger

\trigger

\trigger

\trigger

\trigger

\trigger

\trigger

\trigger

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11):

It's quite easy with expl3:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\newsetcommand}{mm}
  {
   \seq_new:c { g_setcommand_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _seq }
   \seq_gset_split:cnn { g_setcommand_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _seq } {,} {#2}
   \cs_new:Npn #1
     {
      \seq_gpop_left:cN { g_setcommand_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _seq } \l_setcommand_temp_tl
      \seq_gput_right:cV { g_setcommand_ \cs_to_str:N #1 _seq } \l_setcommand_temp_tl
      \tl_use:N \l_setcommand_temp_tl
     }
  }
\tl_new:N \l_setcommand_temp_tl
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_gset_split:Nnn { c }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newsetcommand{\trigger}{out1,out2,out3,out4}

\begin{document}

\trigger

\trigger

\trigger

\trigger

\trigger

\end{document}
```

You see that `\newsetcommand` defines a new macro that expands to the successive elements of the list and as many commands of the same type can be defined.

Here's the output:

[image]

---

### How it works

`\newsetcommand{\trigger}{<list>}` defines

1. A new sequence called `\g_setcommand_trigger_seq`, containing the ordered list got from the comma separated `<list>`
2. A new macro `\trigger` that at each call pops the leftmost element from the associated sequence, adds it on the right of the sequence and prints it.

Since the popped element is added back at the other end of the sequence, when the last original element is printed, the next will be again the first.

---

### "Classical" implementation

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newsetcommand}[2]{%
  \toks@{}%
  \@for\next:=#2\do{%
    \toks@=\expandafter{\the\expandafter\toks@\expandafter{\next}}%
  }
  \expandafter\gdef\csname setcommand\string#1\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\the\toks@}%
  \edef#1{\noexpand\@usecommand{\string#1}}%
}
\def\@usecommand#1{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@@usecommand\csname setcommand#1\endcsname\@nil{#1}\@nil}
\def\@@usecommand#1#2\@nil#3\@nil{%
  #1%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname setcommand#3\endcsname{#2{#1}}%
}
\makeatother
```

The syntax is the same as before.

EDIT

Thanks to David Carlisle's answer, this can be simplified:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newsetcommand}[2]{%
  \global\@namedef{@setcommand\string#1}{#2}%
  \edef#1{\noexpand\@usecommand{\string#1}}%
}
\def\@usecommand#1{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@@usecommand\csname @setcommand#1\endcsname\@nil#1\@nil
}
\def\@@usecommand#1,#2\@nil#3\@nil{%
  \global\@namedef{@setcommand#3}{#2,#1}%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. However, it doesn't work. What is printed is ',out1,out2,out3,out4' (all on the same line). Also, I edited my original question a little: I'd like to reset the loop after the last string is printed, such that a fifth \trigger would produce 'out1' again.

Comment: I changed the implementation to fulfill your request. You perhaps have an outdated version of the expl3 packages. I may try a "classical" implementation, but this one is surely more efficient.

Comment: Thanks! It was indeed an outdated version I had. Next thing to do is taking a good look at expl3, as its possibilities look very promising!

Answer (score 7):

My humble attempt with `etoolbox`, thanks to one of [Leo Liu's answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37426/create-an-array-of-variables/37429#37429). I used `\csdef` and `\csuse` to store and use the values, and `\DeclareListParser` to iterate through the items in the comma-separated list. Finally, the modulo feature is provided by the `intcalc` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{intcalc}

\DeclareListParser*{\myforeach}{,}

\newcounter{helpercounter}
\newcommand{\savethistext}[1]{%
\stepcounter{helpercounter}%
\csdef{triggerval\thehelpercounter}{#1}}

\newcounter{progresscounter}
\newcommand{\trigger}[1]{%
\setcounter{progresscounter}{\intcalcMod{\value{progresscounter} + 1}{\value{helpercounter} + 1}}%
\csuse{triggerval\theprogresscounter}\par%
}

\myforeach{\savethistext}{out1, out2, out3, out4}

\begin{document}

\trigger

\trigger

\trigger

\trigger

\trigger

\trigger

\trigger

\trigger

\trigger

\trigger

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 7):

Here is an implementation using high-level ConTeXt features: `counters` and `conversion`.

```
\defineconversion[trigger][out1, out2, out3, out4]
\definestructurecounter[trigger][numberconversion=trigger]
\setstructurecounter[trigger]{0}

\def\trigger%
    {\incrementstructurecounter[trigger]%
     \convertedstructurecounter[trigger]}

\starttext
\startlines
\trigger
\trigger
\trigger
\trigger
\trigger
\stoplines
\stoptext
```

Comment: ConTeXt seems to make complicated things look so easy. `:)`

Comment: @PauloCereda: The reason is that the internal code is modular. For example, this feature is needed when you use symbols to denote footnotes (`\star`, `\daggar`, `\ddaggar`, etc). Both LaTeX and ConTeXt have internal mechanisms for that; the difference is that in LaTeX it is hidden from the user, while ConTeXt provides a user API for it.

Comment: Ah I see. Providing a consistent user API is really a great approach, so the internal structures can be easily modified in a higher level. Now I'm more tempted to try ConTeXt. `:)`