# Create an array of variables with string keys

Tags: macros

I'd like to have a macro where I can insert a key as argument and get a value which I have defined before.
This should be similar to [Create an array of variables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37426/create-an-array-of-variables) but with strings/text instead of numbers.

The usage should look like:

```
\setprefix{foaf}{http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/}
```

and later

```
\getprefix{foaf}
```

which should return `http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/`.
When I try to use the code from the before mentioned question I get `! Illegal parameter number in definition of`.

Comment: This is more or less exactly what LaTeX's `\@namedef` and `\@nameuse` do. Or [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)' `\csdef` and `\csuse`.

Comment: What will your definitions contain? URLs only?

Comment: @Werner yes only URIs. I just realized, after checking all these answers, that it didn't work for me because I had a hash `#` in one URI which resulted in the `! Illegal parameter number in definition of`.

Comment: @white_gecko: Then you can include the [`url` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/url) and change `#2` in [David's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114673/5764) to `\url{#2}`.

Comment: Thank you David Carlisle, egreg and Steve B. Segletes all your answer work for me :-)
My final result is here: https://gist.github.com/white-gecko/5595112

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\def\setprefix#1#2{\expandafter\def\csname MY@#1\endcsname{#2}}

\def\getprefix#1{\csname MY@#1\endcsname}
```

Should be all you need. The `MY@` internal prefix is arbitrary and just needs to be distinct from other prefixes (so don't use `LT@` unless you want to break `longtable`). By using different strings there you can have different arrays of macros.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `\csname...\endcsname`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\setprefix[2]{\global\@namedef{gecko@\detokenize{#1}}{#2}}
\newcommand{\getprefix}[1]{%
  \@ifundefined{gecko@\detokenize{#1}}
    {\@latex@warning{No prefix `\detokenize{#1}' defined}UNKNOWN}%
    {\@nameuse{gecko@\detokenize{#1}}}%
}
\makeatother

\setprefix{foaf}{http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/}
\setprefix{\just#stupid@input}{http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/}

\begin{document}

\getprefix{foaf}

\getprefix{fuaf}

\getprefix{\just#stupid@input}

\end{document}
```

In the first argument of `\setprefix` you're basically limited in using only balanced braces.

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\setprefix[2]{\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname{#2}}
\newcommand\getprefix[1]{\csname#1\endcsname}
\begin{document}
\setprefix{foaf}{http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/}
\getprefix{foaf}
\end{document}
```

Note also that you can recall the prefix with `\key`, in the example `\foaf` (only as long as the key is alphabetic).

ROLLBACK to original answer, removing caveat.

Comment: The keys do not have to be alphabetic but can be anything: `\setprefix{?.3$a}{foo}\useprefix{?.3$a}` will work just fine

Comment: Why the edit? `\expandafter\def\csname ?.3$a\endcsname{foo}` and then `\csname ?.3$a\endcsname` _does_ work without problems! Your initial solution did suffice just fine! (I'd had upvoted but I'm out of votes for today...)

Comment: @cgnieder I did not know that I could put strange characters inside a csname. Now if I only knew how to undo an edit...

Comment: There should be a rollback button if you look at the edit history