# Use komavar outside scrlttr2

Tags: koma-script

I'm deriving my own class from `scrartcl` but wan to introduce variables as in `scrlttr2` for the user of the class to set several values. I find the `\setkomavar` resp. `\usekomavar` mechanism with key, value and description quite convenient.

Is there any way of using komavars if I'm not using the `scrlttr2` class?

**My actual problem**

Currently I get `Undefined control sequence. \setkomavar` if I use `\setkomavar`.

My new class will have a title page which includes an address and a logo which I want to set with komavars as it is done in scrlttr2. To define this titlepage I renew the `\maketitle` command, which is not available if I would derive my class from `scrlttr2`.

Comment: No, `\newkomavar` is only defined in `scrlttr2.cls` (and will be in `scrletter.sty`). You could however extract it from the definition.

Comment: There are other ways for the user to set variables. What do you have in mind? A short example (great if its compilable) will make it easier to help.

Comment: Ok, I hope I could make my point a little bit more understandable with this edit.

Comment: Please look at the very bottom of this answer: [How to add a flyleaf code?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/210280)

Comment: Ok, that looks good in the way that I could add titlepages to scrlttr with this package but I will not be able to change the descriptions of the values `Gutachter`, `2. Gutachter`, … in your example.

Comment: This is not your first question on TeX.SX, you know how to provide information in a way, that a helper understands what you are after.

Comment: You are developing a class (for scientific writing i guess) and want to have a titlepage. You can use a class like `scrreprt` and use the `titlepage` project. If you give us some detailed information, we will be able to help you in a less generic way.

Comment: I appreciate your help and I'm sorry if there are any misunderstandings.

Comment: No need to feel sorry, i just had a bad start. ;-) sorry.

Comment: I'm developing a class, that is correct but unfortunately it is not for scientific writing but rather a brochure. I've already created the theme with `pstricks` and now want to add some placeholders for values, which the user will be able to set, while some will have a description, which might be changed (the whole layout is not as fixed as e.g. for a thesis). So I found the way komvar is doing it quite flexible (with key, value and description) but I think in the end any simple key-value mechanism should do the trick as well.

Comment: Ok, as it seams `\csdef` and `\csuse` from `etoolbox` is what I'm looking for (http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37429/11820).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19014/discussion-between-johannes-b-and-white-gecko).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good general replacement for komavar is `\csdef`, `\csuse` from `etoolbox` as explained here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37429/11820

A usage scenario is this:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{simplevar}[2014/11/27 simplevar package]

\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

% Set a value for a key
\newcommand\setVar[2]{\csdef{simpleVarValue#1}{#2}}
% Get the value for the key
\newcommand\getVar[1]{\csuse{simpleVarValue#1}}

% Set a label for a key
\newcommand\setLabel[2]{\csdef{simpleVarLabel#1}{#2}}
% Get the label for a key
\newcommand\getLabel[1]{\csuse{simpleVarLabel#1}}

\endinput
```

It could also be extended to use the same syntax as komavar or maybe one could introduce a kind of namespace to make the `simpleVar…` part configurable.

Comment: Sounds interesting. Can you extend the answer and show us an example?

Comment: Under the hood, the `scrlttr2` does something pretty simmilar. But KOMA does some tests to issue errors when the user inputs faulty stuff.

Answer (score 4):

With the [current version of KOMA-script](http://www.komascript.de/current) you get package `scrletter` which is is still in beta. It provides the ability to write letters with the with the article, report or book class of KOMA-script. Hence, it defines the mechanism you want.
In the following a simple example to set the page header with the name.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{scrletter}
\newkomavar[Autor:]{name}
\setkomavar{name}{White Gecko}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\ohead*{\usekomavar*{name}~\usekomavar{name}}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```