# How to have 2 arrays of variables in one document

Tags: arrays, environment-variables

I've used an example from

[Create an array of variables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37426/create-an-array-of-variables?newreg=0c03db8305c740c8b7d3a58816035b45)

By adding a new `\newcommand` as in the code below:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{cnt}
\newcommand\textlist{}
\newcommand\settext[2]{%
  \csdef{text#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\addtext[1]{%
  \stepcounter{cnt}%
  \csdef{text\thecnt}{#1}}
\newcommand\gettext[1]{%
  \csuse{text#1}}

\newcounter{newcnt}
\newcommand\newtextlist{}
\newcommand\setnewtext[2]{%
  \csdef{text#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\addnewtext[1]{%
  \stepcounter{newcnt}%
  \csdef{text\thenewcnt}{#1}}
\newcommand\getnewtext[1]{%
  \csuse{text#1}}


\begin{document}

\addtext{one}
\addtext{two}
\addtext{three}
\settext{100}{one hundred}

 This is text \gettext{1} and \gettext{3}, that is text \gettext{2}.
 100 is \gettext{100}.\\

 Add new info into newtext.
\addnewtext{four}
\addnewtext{five}
\addnewtext{six}
\setnewtext{100}{seven hundred}

 This is newtext \getnewtext{1} and \getnewtext{3}, that is newtext \getnewtext{2}.

 100 is \getnewtext{100}.\\

 This is text \gettext{1} and \gettext{3}, that is text \gettext{2}.
 100 is \gettext{100}.\\

\end{document}
```

The first call of `gettext` will give a correct answer: *One, two, three*.
But the second `gettext` will get data same as `getnewtext` above it: *Four, Five, six*.

How can I make it back as before which is *One, Two, Three*?
Thank You.

Comment: `\csdef{newtext#1}...` and similarly for the other `text#1` etc. in the second group.

Comment: What is `\textlist` supposed to do? It doesn't seem to do anything right now.

Comment: There are better ways to do this, I think. Some of the other answers there demonstrate some of them. For example, the one about **etoolbox**'s list functions etc. (which may not have existed when the code you're using was written, I'm not sure, but they do now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maintain as many arrays (actually property lists) as you want, with a consistent interface with `expl3`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% 1. The user interface
% 1a. \additem[<name>]{<text>}
\NewDocumentCommand{\additem}{ O{default} m }
 {
  \ramiza_array_add:nnn { #1 } { } { #2 }
 }
% 1b. \setitem[<name>]{<slot>}{<text>}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setitem}{ O{default} m m }
 {
  \ramiza_array_add:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
 }
% 1c. \getitem[<name>]{<slot>}
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\getitem}{ O{default} m }
 {
  \ramiza_array_get:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

% 2. The internal functions
\cs_new_protected:Nn \ramiza_array_add:nnn
 {% if the array doesn't exist yet, allocate it with its related counter
  \prop_if_exist:cF { g_ramiza_array_#1_prop }
   {
    \prop_new:c { g_ramiza_array_#1_prop }
    \int_new:c { g_ramiza_array_#1_int }
   }
  \tl_if_empty:nTF { #2 }
   {% with \additem we step the counter and set the next slot
    \int_gincr:c { g_ramiza_array_#1_int }
    \prop_gput:cvn { g_ramiza_array_#1_prop } { g_ramiza_array_#1_int } { #3 }
   }
   {% with \setitem we set the requested slot
    \prop_gput:cnn { g_ramiza_array_#1_prop } { #2 } { #3 }
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_gput:Nnn { cv }

\cs_new:Nn \ramiza_array_get:nn
 {% retrieve the requested item
  \prop_item:cn { g_ramiza_array_#1_prop } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\additem{one}
\additem{two}
\additem{three}
\setitem{100}{one hundred}

This is text \getitem{1} and \getitem{3}, that is text \getitem{2}. 100 is \getitem{100}.

Add new info into newtext.
\additem[new]{four}
\additem[new]{five}
\additem[new]{six}
\setitem[new]{100}{seven hundred}

This is newtext \getitem[new]{1} and \getitem[new]{3}, that is newtext \getitem[new]{2}.

100 is \getitem[new]{100}.

This is text \getitem{1} and \getitem{3}, that is text \getitem{2}. 100 is \getitem{100}.

\end{document}
```

There is a “default” array, which you access without the optional argument to `\additem`, `\setitem` or `\getitem`; as soon as you use the optional argument to `\additem` or `\setitem`, a new array is allocated, to be used with `\getitem`.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `newtext#1` etc. rather than `text#1` etc. in the second list. These are defining macro names. You want them to be unique or you'll overwrite the old definitions.

Oh, and don't use `\\` to break lines in ordinary contexts (outside `tabular`, `array` etc.).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{cnt}
\newcommand\textlist{}
\newcommand\settext[2]{%
  \csdef{text#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\addtext[1]{%
  \stepcounter{cnt}%
  \csdef{text\thecnt}{#1}}
\newcommand\gettext[1]{%
  \csuse{text#1}}

\newcounter{newcnt}
\newcommand\newtextlist{}
\newcommand\setnewtext[2]{%
  \csdef{newtext#1}{#2}}
\newcommand\addnewtext[1]{%
  \stepcounter{newcnt}%
  \csdef{newtext\thenewcnt}{#1}}
\newcommand\getnewtext[1]{%
  \csuse{newtext#1}}


\begin{document}

\addtext{one}
\addtext{two}
\addtext{three}
\settext{100}{one hundred}

 This is text \gettext{1} and \gettext{3}, that is text \gettext{2}.
 100 is \gettext{100}.

 Add new info into newtext.
\addnewtext{four}
\addnewtext{five}
\addnewtext{six}
\setnewtext{100}{seven hundred}

 This is newtext \getnewtext{1} and \getnewtext{3}, that is newtext \getnewtext{2}.

 100 is \getnewtext{100}.

 This is text \gettext{1} and \gettext{3}, that is text \gettext{2}.
 100 is \gettext{100}.

\end{document}
```