# Additional row when using pgfkeys inside a table

Tags: tables, pgfkeys

Inspired by the answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37484, I tried to create a table with a key-value interface. Using `\pgfkeys` only outside of the tabular environment works as intended, but if it is used inside the environment, it starts an additional row as in my first and second approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys, pgffor}

% set up
\pgfkeys{table/.is family, table, 
    list of fields/.initial={foo, bar},
    add field/.style={#1/.value required, #1/.initial={undefined}},
    add field/.list/.expanded=\pgfkeysvalueof{/table/list of fields}
}

% first approach
\pgfkeys{table,
    print row/.code = {#1 & \pgfkeysvalueof{/table/#1} \\\hline},
    print table/.style = {print row/.list/.expanded = \pgfkeysvalueof{/table/list of fields}}
}

% second approach
\pgfkeys{table,
    content/.initial={},
    print content/.code=\pgfkeysvalueof{/table/content},
    add row/.style = {
        % 3 pairs of braces are needed if pgfkeys is called within a table
        content/.append={{{#1 & \pgfkeysvalueof{/table/#1} \\\hline}}},
    }, 
    fill content/.style = {add row/.list/.expanded = \pgfkeysvalueof{/table/list of fields}},
    create table/.style = {fill content, print content}
}

\parindent=0pt 
\begin{document}
    \pgfkeys{table, foo=1}

    first approach:\\
    \begin{tabular}{|l | l |}
        \hline
        \pgfkeys{table, print table}%
    \end{tabular}       

    \bigskip    
    second approach:\\
    \begin{tabular}{|l | l |}
        \hline
        \pgfkeys{table, create table}% here 3 braces are needed, see above
    \end{tabular}

    \bigskip
    use key directly:\\
    \pgfkeys{table, fill content}% would work with single pair of braces
    \begin{tabular}{|l | l |}
        \hline
        \pgfkeysvalueof{/table/content}
    \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

What causes the additional row and how can it be removed? Also I wonder why three pairs of braces are necessary for appending a row inside the table, while normally it works fine with just a single pair.

**Edit:**

I realized that many things can add a new row at the end of a table, e.g.,

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    a & b \\\hline\relax
\end{tabular}
```

It seems that the following hack works, but I guess avoiding `\pgfkeys` at the end of a table is the easier solution:

```
\pgfkeys{table,
    print head/.code = {\begin{tabular}{|l | l |}\hline\bgroup},
    print foot/.code = {\egroup\end{tabular}},
    print row/.code = {\egroup#1 & \pgfkeysvalueof{/table/#1} \\\hline\noalign\bgroup},
    print table/.style = {print head, print row/.list/.expanded = \pgfkeysvalueof{/table/list of fields}, print foot}
}

\pgfkeys{table, print table}
```

Comment: you are trying to reinvent the `pgfplotstable` package.

Comment: Maybe the `pgfplotstable` package can be used as well for the underlying problem, i.e., providing a macro like `\createtable{field1 = foo, field2 = bar, ...}`. But this was already solved in the answer I referenced in the beginning. In this question, I just wanted to understand the special behavior of `\pgfkeys` inside the `tabular` environment, as I use it a lot and was suprised that my approaches didn't work.

Comment: I agree that `pgfplotstable` provides a nice interface for the input of tabled data.  However, if I want to handle missing or misspelled entries, I don't know how to do that with `pgfplotstable`, but it can be done easily with `pgfkeys`.

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error I have learned that all(?) but empty commands add an additional row if they are called at the end of a tabular environment, even if they have no visible effect on the output otherwise. An arbitrary example is:

```
\begin{tabular}{|l | l |}
    \hline
    a & b \\\hline\stepcounter{count}
\end{tabular}
```

[image: Table with additional row]

If one does not want to avoid a command at the end of the last row, `\noalign` can be used to suppress the additional row, e.g.,

```
\begin{tabular}{|l | l |}
    \hline
    a & b \\\hline\noalign{\stepcounter{count}}
\end{tabular}
```

This can even be used from inside `\pgfkeys`, see the edit of my question. A simple example for this is:

```
\pgfkeys{row/.code={a & b\\\noalign\bgroup}}
\begin{tabular}{|l | l |}
    \hline
    \pgfkeys{row}\egroup
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

I am still interested in an explanation, but at the moment I will just accept this as another mystery of (La)Tex.