# Counting of selected words

Tags: counters, word-count

I am typesetting a book, which has got more number of plants. While entering the text, I have to record the total number of plants recorded in my book.

In fact, I have created an index of all these plants, but the question is should I count manually, or LaTeX can count itself.

Here is my simple  document.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

%For multiple index
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
 \makeindex[name=ch, title=Chemical index]
\makeindex[name=pl,title=Plant Index]

\begin{document}

This is my test docment. It contains total 5 plants. Plant 1\index[pl]{plant 1}  has                
chemicals 1\index[ch]{chemical 1} and 2\index[ch]{chemical 2}. Another plant\index[pl]
{plant 2} continas the chemicals 2\index[ch]{chemical 2} and 3\index[ch]{chemical 3}.

List of plants:
Plant 3\index[pl]{plant 3}
plant 4\index[pl]{plant 4}
plant 5\index[pl]{plant 5}

\printindex
\indexprologue{\small Index of plants}
\printindex[pl]

\indexprologue{\small Index of chemicals}
\printindex[ch]

\end{document}
```

Comment: How are you inputting the plants' names?

Comment: are you entering plants in the document using some macro? That is, at every occurence of a word you want to count is there in fact `\macro{word I want to count}`? Where macros can be different? Theny ou could just increase a counter whenever the macro is called.

Comment: Just use an own `\plant` macro to format all plant names and which increases a count which can be displayed at the very end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `.idx` file for counting:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

%For multiple index
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=ch, title=Chemical index]
\makeindex[name=pl,title=Plant Index]

\begin{document}

This is my test document. It contains a total of \ref{plants-number} plants. Plant 
1\index[pl]{plant 1} has chemicals 1\index[ch]{chemical 1} and 2\index[ch]{chemical 2}. 
Another plant\index[pl]{plant 2} continas the chemicals 2\index[ch]{chemical 2} and 
3\index[ch]{chemical 3}.

List of plants:
Plant 3\index[pl]{plant 3}
plant 4\index[pl]{plant 4}
plant 5\index[pl]{plant 5}

\indexprologue{\small Index of plants}
\printindex[pl]

\indexprologue{\small Index of chemicals}
\printindex[ch]

% We'll count the number of plants and of chemicals
\newcounter{items}
\makeatletter
\begingroup
% Define suitably \indexentry
\newcommand{\indexentry}[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{#1}
    {\refstepcounter{items}\expandafter\let\csname#1\endcsname\@empty}
    {}}

% Let's count the plants
\begingroup
\setcounter{items}{0}
\input{pl.idx}\label{plants-number}
\endgroup

% Let's count the chemicals
\begingroup
\setcounter{items}{0}
\input{ch.idx}\label{chemicals-number}
\endgroup

\endgroup

\end{document}
```

The final code will produce no text, but only a reference to the last counted plant; this reference may be used anywhere (but, of course, this requires at least two runs of LaTeX).

Note: there's no need to give a `\makeindex` command and `\printindex` command if you have only entries marked `\index[pl]` and `\index[ch]`.

Comment: 1. clarification of \makeindex comment. I could not understand.   2. Same logic can i apply to count chemicals also?

Comment: 1. If there's no `\index{something}` command, so that you don't have a "main index", then `\makeindex` and  `\printindex` are useless. 2. Yes, of course. I'll add it.

Answer (score 9):

LaTeX provides built-in macros to handle counters and that is how the sectioning numbering, page numbers and floats are handled. In https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19761/963 I posted a reply which is very similar to what you want to do and which I have adapted to include counters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lstdoc,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter

\newcounter{cnt}
\setcounter{cnt}{0}
\let\alist\@empty

\def\addtolist#1#2{%
  \lst@lAddTo#1{#2}
}

\def\RA#1|#2|#3|#4;{%
  \addtolist{\alist}{#1#2,}%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname#1#2\endcsname{\textit{#1}&#2&#3&#4\cr\relax}
  \lst@BubbleSort{\alist}
  \stepcounter{cnt}
}

\def\RB#1|#2|#3|#4;{%
   \addtolist{\alist}{#2#1,}%
   \expandafter\gdef\csname#2#1\endcsname{\textit{#1}&#2&#3&#4\cr\relax}
   \lst@BubbleSort{\alist}
}

%% adding the data now
\RA Lactarius fallax      | velvety milk cap |edible |potentially risky;  
\RA Lactarius camphoratus | candy cap        |edible |aromatic qualities;
\RA Suillus pungens       | slippery Jack    |edible |poor taste;
\RA Lactarius affinis     | kindred milk     |edible |unpalatable;
\RA Calocybe carnea       | pink fairhead    |edible |potentially risky;
\RA Amateta ocreata       | death angel      |inedible |highly poisonous;   

%% typesetting the table
\newsavebox{\tempbox}
\savebox{\tempbox}{
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llll}
  \toprule[1pt]
  Species & Common name & Edibility & Remarks\\
  \midrule
  \@for\i:=\alist \do{\csname\i\endcsname}
  \vspace{-14pt}\\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{table}
\usebox{\tempbox}
\caption{Some mushrooms from Wikipedia}
\end{table}

Number of mushrooms in database is \textbf{\thecnt}

\end{document}
```

The idea is that everytime you add a plant (in my examples is mushrooms), you first add it to a database macro (just a comma delimited list really) and you increment the counter. Pretty much similar to when you adding something to an index. Depending on the structure of the document, the code can be adapted to hold an image, increment a number, sort alphabetically etc. In the example we just display the names in a table.

Answer (score 8):

LateX provides the command `\newcounter` and `\stepcounter` and some other for counting.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{plants}
\newcommand{\plant}[1]{%
    % step counter
    \stepcounter{plants}% use \refstepcounter if you want
        % to use the number with the \ref-\label-mechanism
    % new line
    \par
    % optionally print counter
%   \theplants. 
    % print name
    #1
}


\begin{document}
\plant{Foo}
\plant{Bar}
\plant{Baz}

Sum: \theplants
\end{document}
```

To specify my answer I need more information about you project. Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: i have included the MWE -Anil

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `xetex`, you could use the `xesearch` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xesearch}
\newcounter{plants}
\setcounter{plants}{0}
\def\plantlist{tree?,grass,flower?}
\SearchList{list1}{#1\stepcounter{plants}}{\plantlist}
\begin{document}
    ``What is your favorite kind of plant? Trees, grass, or flowers?''
    ``I like trees because they are much taller than grass and flowers.''
\end{document}
```

This code creates a counter called `plants`, then searches for a word found in `\plantlist` and increments the counter each time a word from the list is found.

- Add any word that you want to have counted to the list in line 5. E.g. `tree,grass,flower`.
- If you will be writing plural forms, add those to the list too, or use "?" or "*" to match those forms. E.g. `tree?` will match "tree" and "trees" and `cact*` will match "catcus" and "cacti".
- To display the final number of matching words, place `\arabic{plants}` at the end of your document.