# What is the best _hack_ you have seen or written in (La)TeX?

Tags: big-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cunning (La)TeX tricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19746/cunning-latex-tricks)

Here, by *hack* I mean a short, elegant, or even counterintuitive definition/macro etc. that solves a task, often in a surprising way.

Background

Many languages/systems collect those lists of hacks, as there are a fun way to learn some of the intricacies of that language/system. Very often, such lists reveal nuggets and shortcomings of said language/system. Yes, even the shortcomings, as something that qualifies as a *hack* in one language is a boring one-liner in another language, because the task at hand is built in.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/pearls).