# Bizarre spacing of \cdot when trying to typeset a permutation type

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I was just trying to write some cycle types in a permutation group, like so:

```
The conjugacy classes of the symmetric group are simply given by the
cycle types, so there are five in $S_4$: $Id$, $(\cdot \cdot)$,
$(\cdot \cdot)(\cdot \cdot)$, $(\cdot \cdot \cdot)$, and $(\cdot \cdot
\cdot \cdot)$.
```

But I get rather odd results:

[image: screenshot of output from code above]

I guess the weird spacing is the result of LaTeX interpreting the `\cdot` as an operator and trying to space things out so that they fit on the line nicely, but the non-uniformity is disturbing.  What's the correct way to do what I'm trying to do here?

UPDATE: Changing the spaces to `~`'s helps, but the spacing is still a bit uneven.

Comment: David and Werner have of course given the answer(s) to your problem but there is another small thing: The identity operator (I assume `$Id$` means that) should be declared using `\DeclareMathOperator{\Id}{Id}` in the preamble.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`\cdot` is a binary operator so gets spacing either side, but if it is used in a non-infix position it loses its spacing and turns into a mathord so two `\cdot` are two mathord, but three `\cdot` the end ones become mathord but the middle one stays as a `\mathbin`. If you make them all `\mathord` you get:

[image]

```
The conjugacy classes of the symmetric group are simply given by the cycle types,
so there are five in 
$S_4$: $Id$, $({\cdot} {\cdot})$,
$({\cdot} {\cdot})({\cdot} {\cdot})$,
$({\cdot} {\cdot} {\cdot})$, and
$({\cdot} {\cdot} {\cdot} {\cdot})$

\bye
```

Answer (score 9):

You can experiment with `\dotspacing` in the following code, so you can define what spacing pleases you more:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\dotspacing}{1mu}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\bcdot}{O{1}}
 {
  { \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { {\cdot}\mkern\dotspacing } \mkern-\dotspacing }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\test}{$\mathit{Id}$, $(\bcdot)$,
$(\bcdot[2])$, $(\bcdot[3])$,
$(\bcdot[4])$, $(\bcdot[5])$.}

\test

\renewcommand{\dotspacing}{1.5mu}\test

\renewcommand{\dotspacing}{2mu}\test

\renewcommand{\dotspacing}{2.5mu}\test

\renewcommand{\dotspacing}{3mu}\test

\end{document}
```

Note the use of `$\mathit{Id}$`, rather than `$Id$`, that gives a better rendering.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

An alternative suggestion in terms of the output is given in the last example below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,multido}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmath,multido}
\newcommand{\conjclass}[1]{%
  \def\conjclasssep{\def\conjclasssep{\,}}%
  \ifnum#1>0\relax
    \multido{\i=1+1}{#1}{\conjclasssep{\cdot}}
  \fi%
}
\begin{document}
The conjugacy classes of the symmetric group are simply given by 
the cycle types, so there are five in $S_4$: $Id$, $(\cdot \cdot)$, 
$(\cdot \cdot)(\cdot \cdot)$, $(\cdot \cdot \cdot)$, and $(\cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot)$.

The conjugacy classes of the symmetric group are simply given by 
the cycle types, so there are five in $S_4$: $\text{Id}$, $(\cdot{}\cdot)$, 
$(\cdot{}\cdot)(\cdot{}\cdot)$, $(\cdot{}\cdot{}\cdot)$, and 
$(\cdot{}\cdot{}\cdot{}\cdot)$.

The conjugacy classes of the symmetric group are simply given by 
the cycle types, so there are five in $S_4$: $\text{Id}$, $({\cdot}{\cdot})$, 
$({\cdot}{\cdot})({\cdot}{\cdot})$, $({\cdot}{\cdot}{\cdot})$, and 
$({\cdot}{\cdot}{\cdot}{\cdot})$.

The conjugacy classes of the symmetric group are simply given by 
the cycle types, so there are five in $S_4$: $\text{Id}$, $(\conjclass{2})$, 
$(\conjclass{2})(\conjclass{2})$, $(\conjclass{3})$, and $(\conjclass{4})$.
\end{document}
```

The last example provides `\conjclass{<num>}` which sets `\cdot` as a "`\mathord`" (using `{\cdot}`), but also prints `<num>` with a predefined spacing `\,` between each element. Depending on your usage (quantity), it promotes consistency when defining a macro (see [Consistent typography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/29840/5764)).

The technique used to delay the initial space is from [Cunning (La)TeX tricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89187/5764).

As a side-note: See the use of `$\text{Id}$` instead of `$Id$`. It looks better...