# Variadic arguments macro

Tags: macros, tex-core, expansion

I am trying to make macro with variadic arguments, iterating over them.
The final result is supposed to be:

```
\foreach[x]((var = \x )){foo}{bar}{baz}\null
```

evals to

```
var = foo var = bar var = baz
```

My naive guess is this one:

```
\def\Macro#1{\if \null#1 . \else ,\noexpand\Macro \fi}
\Macro foogg\null
```

I expected it to eval to `,,,,,.`, but it evals to `,oogg`. 
Am I understanding `\noexpand` behavior wrong?

Comment: Can you please clarify your aim? However, the test `\if\null#1` will always evaluate to false, because `\if` expands tokens and the expansion of `\null` is `\hbox{}`, so `\if` is comparing `\hbox` to `{`.

Comment: Many list parsers (like [`pgffor`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgffor) and [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox)) would be able to assist in your task. See [Cunning (La)TeX tricks](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89187/5764), for example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change `\noexpand` to `\expandafter`, that's what you need to "skip" that `\fi`. As well, as **egreg** points out, `\if\null` won't work. Either use `\ifx`, or change `\null` to `\relax` and hope it is not contained in your text. The reason why `\relax` will work is that it is unexpandable and `\if` takes it, instead of expanding. For the reason that `\relax` or `\null` might be used by someone else, a much safer option is to use a command that doesn't exist, like `\thisIStoheczSdelimiter`:

```
\def\Macro#1{\ifx\thisIStoheczSdelimiter#1 . \else ,\expandafter\Macro \fi}
\Macro foogg\thisIStoheczSdelimiter
```

---

As for working `foreach` cycles, look into [`pgffor`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) package. Your code, IIRC, could be rewritten as

```
\foreach \x in {foo, bar, baz}{ var = \x, }
```

Comment: It's not sufficient; see my other comment.

Comment: I know, I missed that it's not `\ifx`. I'll correct.

Answer (score 8):

```
\def\Macro#1{\if \null#1 . \else ,\noexpand\Macro \fi}
\Macro foogg\null

\def\xnull{\null}
\def\Macro#1{\def\tmp{#1}\ifx\tmp\xnull\else ,#1\expandafter\Macro \fi}
\Macro foogg\null

\bye
```

produces `,foogg` from your original then `,f,o,o,g,g` from the modified version, in your original the `\noexpand` makes `\Macro` act like `\relax` and so do nothing after the first call, so only `f` is ever taken as an argument.

The above is plain TeX, but if you are intending this for LaTeX you should really use a different syntax, one of the main aims of LaTeX is to give a unifying syntactic structure, and LaTeX commands *never* take a variable number of `{}` arguments. The LaTeX syntax would be a comma separated list within a single `{}` argument.