# Is it possible to use the pipe character, |, to separate cells in a table?

Tags: tables

I was wondering if it is possible to use the pipe character, `|`, instead of the `&` to separate cells.

Something like this:

```
c1 | c2 | c3 \\
c4 | c5 | c6 \\
```

instead of this:

```
c1 & c2 & c3 \\
c4 & c5 & c6 \\
```

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19761/963 and you get free sorting as well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are not using `|` for anything else

```
\catcode`\|=4
```

Answer (score 13):

Instead of (inherently fragile) catcode trickery, as suggested by David, you could also define a simple helper macro with delimited arguments:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

  \def\row#1|#2|#3\\{#1 & #2 & #3 \tabularnewline}
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \row c1 | c2 | c3 \\
    \row c4 | c5 | c6 \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Even though the extra `\row` at the beginning of each row is a bit more to type, it also brings you some extra flexibility: You now can easily rearrange, skip, or format columns, *by just changing the definition of `\row`*: For instance, `\def\row#1|#2|#3\\{\textbf{#1} & & #3 \tabularnewline}` would typset the first column in boldface and (maybe temporarily) skip the second column.

Comment: Nice, but redefining the catcode of `|` is just as fragile as using `&` (assuming one does not use `|` anywhere else, which is quite probable.  In fact, even `\verb&verbatim text&` works under the normal LaTeX catcode regime, by the way, so David's answer does not conflict with the usual `\verb|blah|`.)

Comment: Of course, your `\row` will break with a number of columns different from three.

Comment: @egreg: Sure, the idea is to define it for each table as needed.

Comment: Having to redefine the command poses a bit of a burden on the user and may introduce errors. Why not make the `\row` a bit more intelligent so it'll work for any number of columns?

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: In my actual applications, `\row` is also used to define the formatting of table columns, which often is specific to a table anyway. In many cases I find this less of a burden and more understandable than dealing with `\newcolumntype` and other trickery.

Comment: @Daniel Using TeX's pattern matching (delimiters) you can define the `\row` command parse the arguments and insert the columns and column separators on the fly. You have the newline (`\\`) at the end of the row and you can use this to detect the last column.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: I know that I could do this. My point is that **(a)** I don't think redefining `\row` per table is much of a burden, especially as **(b)** I often use it also to implement formatting options for certain columns (such as math mode, a surrounding  TikZ node, ...) which IMHO is way easier to do in the `\row` macro than by a fancy table preamble. So `\row` is specifically defined for each table anyway.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a ConTeXt solution using the `database` module. The idea is to define a
separated list with a vertical bar as separator and table macros as
delimiters. Example:

```
\usemodule [database]

\defineseparatedlist
  [Table]
  [separator=|,
   before=\bTABLE, after=\eTABLE,
   first=\bTR, last=\eTR,
   left=\bTD, right=\eTD]

\starttext
  \startTable
    alpha | beta   | gamma
    first | second | third
  \stopTable
\stoptext
```

[image: result]

As separators the strings `comma` (default), `tab`, or `space` can be used or just any character like I did with the vertical bar here.

The same technique can be used to typeset CSV data as well since the macros,
separators and the quoting can be configured.