# Problem with table

Tags: tables

I'm trying to create a table for my thesis. I'm quite noob in LaTeX so I will request some charity help

I already done the table in but in other format. See the attachment.

[image: table_ex]

Regards

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
 \begin{document}

 \begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}

    \begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}[4]{*}{\textbf{Nível na albufeira (m)}} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{\textbf{QM.FÍSICO (m3/s)}} & \multirow{2}[4]{*}{\textbf{QDIM. (m3/s)}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{1st order Mom. Adv}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{2nd order Mom. Adv}} \\
    \midrule
          &       &       & \textbf{QCFD (m3/s)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Erro (\%)}} & \textbf{QCFD (m3/s)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Erro (\%)}} \\
    \textbf{260,4} & \textbf{100} & \textbf{88,3} & \textbf{81,9} & \textbf{-18.1} & \textbf{-7.3} & \textbf{83,3} & \textbf{-16.7} & \textbf{-5.7} \\
    \textbf{262,5} & \textbf{250} & \textbf{233,1} & \textbf{223,1} & \textbf{-10.8} & \textbf{-4.3} & \textbf{224,9} & \textbf{-10} & \textbf{-3.5} \\
    \textbf{267,0} & \textbf{750,0} & \textbf{708,9} & \textbf{690,3} & \textbf{-8} & \textbf{-2.6} & \textbf{696,9} & \textbf{-7.1} & \textbf{-1.7} \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:niveis}
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Im not getting the same output like the image attached. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please add a MWE (Minimal Working Example) of the code you already have. Otherwise, it is very hard to guess the actual problem you are having in creating a table.

Comment: You can adapt [Mico's solution](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/104259/21891) with minimal effort.

Comment: How can I make Q_{M.FISICO} in tabular environment with the same aspect as other words, not math aspect?

Comment: If by "aspect" you mean the font (i.e. use the font of the surrounding text instead of the "math font"), you can do `\usepackage{amsmath}`  in the preamble and use `$\text{Q}_{\text{M.FISICO}}$`

Answer (score 3):

I think here is what you need. Improvements:

- `fixltex2e` package for `\textsubscript` command.
- `\cmidrule{4-9}` for rule.
- `2cm` for `\multirow` parameter.
- `\renewcommand\multirowsetup{\centering}` for `\centering` of `\multirow` cells.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[top=1cm,bottom=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[htbp]
    \renewcommand\multirowsetup{\centering}
    \centering
    \caption{Add caption}

    \begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
      \toprule
      \multirow{2}[4]{2cm}{\textbf{N\'ivel na albufeira (m)}} & \multirow{2}[4]{2cm}{\textbf{Q\textsubscript{M.F\'ISICO} (m3/s)}} & \multirow{2}[4]{2cm}{\textbf{Q\textsubscript{DIM.} (m3/s)}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{1st order Mom. Adv}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{2nd order Mom. Adv}} \\
      \cmidrule{4-9}
          &       &       & \textbf{Q\textsubscript{CFD} (m3/s)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Erro (\%)}} & \textbf{Q\textsubscript{CFD} (m3/s)} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Erro (\%)}} \\
      \midrule
      \textbf{260,4} & \textbf{100} & \textbf{88,3} & \textbf{81,9} & \textbf{-18.1} & \textbf{-7.3} & \textbf{83,3} & \textbf{-16.7} & \textbf{-5.7} \\
      \textbf{262,5} & \textbf{250} & \textbf{233,1} & \textbf{223,1} & \textbf{-10.8} & \textbf{-4.3} & \textbf{224,9} & \textbf{-10} & \textbf{-3.5} \\
      \textbf{267,0} & \textbf{750,0} & \textbf{708,9} & \textbf{690,3} & \textbf{-8} & \textbf{-2.6} & \textbf{696,9} & \textbf{-7.1} & \textbf{-1.7} \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:niveis}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Image:**

[image: result pic]

Comment: While this reproduces the OP's picture, I think the numbers should align vertically at their decimal points. I also think that setting all content bold is a bad idea.

Comment: @mafp: I'll left this here: [Aligning numbers by decimal points in table columns](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2746/aligning-numbers-by-decimal-points-in-table-columns).

Comment: Thanks very much mOnhawk! Yeah its right I will try to align numbers vertically at their decimal points.

Answer (score 3):

Shamelessly stealing moonhawk's solution to add some spice with bold and sans-serif fonts. Also the units are now parsed via `siunitx`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[top=1cm,bottom=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow,siunitx}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}

\sisetup{per-mode=symbol,detect-inline-weight=text,text-rm=\bfseries\sffamily,mode=text}
\newcolumntype{B}{>{\bfseries\sffamily}S<{}}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \renewcommand\multirowsetup{\centering}
    \centering
    \caption{Add caption}

    \begin{tabular}{BBBBBBBBB}
      \toprule
      \multirow{2}[4]{2cm}{\bfseries\sffamily N\'{i}vel na albufeira (\si{\meter})} 
     &\multirow{2}[4]{2cm}{\bfseries\sffamily Q\textsubscript{M.F\'ISICO} (\si{\meter\cubed\per\second})} 
     &\multirow{2}[4]{2cm}{\bfseries\sffamily Q\textsubscript{DIM.} (\si{\meter\cubed\per\second})} 
     &\multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries\sffamily 1st order Mom. Adv} 
     &\multicolumn{3}{c}{\bfseries\sffamily 2nd order Mom. Adv} \\
      \cmidrule{4-9}
        &%
        &%
        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries\sffamily Q\textsubscript{CFD}(\si{\meter\cubed\per\second})}%
        &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries\sffamily Error (\si{\percent})} %
        &\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries\sffamily Q\textsubscript{CFD}(\si{\meter\cubed\per\second})}%
        &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\bfseries\sffamily Error (\si{\percent})} \\
      \midrule
      260,4 & 100   &  88,3 &  81,9 & -18.1 & -7.3 &  83,3 & -16.7 & -5.7 \\
      262,5 & 250   & 233,1 & 223,1 & -10.8 & -4.3 & 224,9 & -10   & -3.5 \\
      267,0 & 750,0 & 708,9 & 690,3 &  -8   & -2.6 & 696,9 &  -7.1 & -1.7 \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:niveis}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't see any advantage in having a different typeface in the body of the table than in the main text. Also the numbers aren't aligned properly. (Of course you _should_ make sure the figures are tabular figures.)

Comment: @MarcvanDongen They are aligned with respect to the decimal point.

Comment: No, they're not (yet:-). The dot in the _-7.1_ is partially underneath the _0_ of the _-10_ in the second last column. I think this is caused by the fact that your sans serif doesn't have tabular figures.  (You can also see this in other columns.)

Comment: @MarcvanDongen -10 is actually taken as -10.0 so 7.1 is aligned to the hypothetical dot.

Comment: You have to be kidding. The _7_ is partially underneath the _1_ of the _-10._. The dots in the last column, to me, don't seem to be in the same column.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen Emphasis on the *hypothetical* i.e. zero width. :)