# Inserting automatic vertical space between blocks when \obeylines is active

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, catcodes

Sometimes as I write a manuscript in LaTeX for speaking, I want to format parts
of it as `\obeylines` and `\obeyspaces` permit, so that a single coherent thought
is expressed compactly on each line, and relationships between lines can be
expressed with leading indentation, like this:

```
One thought introduced with a coherent phrase,
    followed by a subordinate phrase,
    and a coordinate subordinate phrase.

Then a second thought introduced ...
```

The problem I run into is including the extra vertical spacing between groups
of contiguous lines ("paragraphs"), as before the last line above.  The best
ad-hoc measure I have come up with so far is to define the pipe symbol, which
can be added to the end of each group, like this: `... coordinate subordinate
phrase.|`

The redefinition code looks like this, which I have placed into an external
package.

```
\catcode`|=\active
\def|{\smallskip}
```

This works more or less as desired, but the pipe characters throughout my
source text are irritating, and obviously a work-around.

So I have been trying to define an environment that accomplishes what I want,
without requiring the pipe character for the extra spacing.  This is what I
have so far...

```
\newenvironment{linewise}{%
\let\@oldpar=\par \let\par=\newpar \obeylines \let\par=\@oldpar}
{}
```

If I proceed in this direction, how should `\newpar` be defined?  I have tried
using `\\`, but TeX balks when this is inserted automatically at the end of an
empty line (where `\par` is normally inserted), and it does not end the previous
paragraph (because the character is `\active`, I presume), which is what I'm trying to do.

As far as I can tell, the problem is that the division between paragraphs at
two or more return characters takes place in TeX's mouth, where I can't make
any adjustments that would distinguish between the vertical space I want to
insert where there are two or more return characters, and the line break (or
new paragraph) I want to insert when there is only one.

Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: is there any reason why a line `\begin{verbatim}` above the block and `\end{verbatim}` just after the block won't suffice? that does exactly what you describe, obeying both spaces and line endings, including those for blank lines.

Comment: Yes, the verbatim environment does a lot more than I really want to do when it suppresses the normal meaning of other LaTeX commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time, I found a better solution to what I was trying to do.  It borrows from eTeX, which has the command `\obeywhitespace`.  I've put the needed definitions (which clearly work, though some look quite involved) into a package I can use when needed.  I'll include the relevant package contents below.

Note that there's a command at the end called `\setblankskip`, which allows an adjustment to the spacing between "paragraphs" as shown in the original question.

Note also that this behavior is provided within an environment called `linewise`.  The only remaining irritation is that the final newline within the `linewise` environment will be reflected in a blank output line.  This can be avoided by preceding that final newline with a `%`.

```
\def\makeactive#1{\catcode`#1 = \active \ignorespaces}%
\def\gobble#1{}%
\newskip\blanklineskipamount
\blanklineskipamount = -.8\baselineskip
\begingroup
   \makeactive\^^M \makeactive\ % No spaces or ^^M's from here on.
\gdef\obeywhitespace{%
\makeactive\^^M\def^^M{\par\futurelet\next\@finishobeyedreturn}%
\makeactive\ \def {\ }%
\aftergroup\@removebox%
\futurelet\next\@finishobeywhitespace%
}%
\gdef\@finishobeywhitespace{{%
\ifx\next %
\aftergroup\@obeywhitespaceloop%
\else\ifx\next^^M%
\aftergroup\gobble%
\fi\fi}}%
\gdef\@finishobeyedreturn{%
\ifx\next^^M\vskip\blanklineskipamount\fi%
\indent%
}%
\endgroup
\def\@obeywhitespaceloop#1{\futurelet\next\@finishobeywhitespace}%
\def\@removebox{%
   \setbox0 = \lastbox
   \ifdim\wd0=\parindent
     \setbox2 = \hbox{\unhbox0}%
     \ifdim\wd2=0pt
       \ignorespaces
     \else
       \box2 % Put it back: it wasn't empty.
     \fi
   \else
      \box0 % Put it back: it wasn't the right width.
   \fi
}%
\newenvironment{linewise}{\begingroup\obeywhitespace}{\endgroup}%
% By default, a blank line will result in .2\baselineskip.  This allows
% other values to be set
\RequirePackage{calc}
\newcommand{\setblankskip}[1]{\setlength{\blanklineskipamount}{-\baselineskip+#1}}
```

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't redefine `\par`, but the active end-of-line after `\obeylines`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{linewise}
  {\parindent=0pt
   \obeyspaces\obeylines
   \begingroup\lccode`~=`\^^M
   \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\par\leavevmode}}
  {\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}
\noindent X\leaders\hrule\hfill X

\begin{linewise}
One thought introduced with a coherent phrase,
    followed by a subordinate phrase,
    and a coordinate subordinate phrase.

Then a second thought introduced ...
\end{linewise}
Something after
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing.  It works perfectly, but I don't understand how.  It reassigns and uses only the lower case value (\lccode) of the tilde (~).  Is that the active end-of-line?

Comment: I also don't understand why \begingroup and \endgroup are needed.  And it appears that \def~ is not isolated from the assigned value because the closing brace (}) from the argument of \lowercase is not a group delimiter, as distinguished in the TeXbook on the middle of p. 20.  Is that right?

Comment: @beny'akov The `\begingroup` with `\endgroup` trick is used to give a meaning to the active end-of-line without needing to activate it at definition time. You can find it in many answers in the site. For instance [in this answer of mine](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19750/4427)