# Can \\ be omitted in verses?

Tags: line-breaking, verse

As far as I know, a double line break introduces a new paragraph. Within `verse` this is used to separate stanzas, which can also be done with `\\!`. So in LaTeX source code for long, standalone poems, almost every line ends with `\\`. Is it possible to use a single line break for newlines instead?

Essentially I have

```
\begin{verse}
There was a young lady of Niger \\
Who smiled as she rode on a tiger; \\
They returned from the ride \\
With the lady inside, \\
And the smile on the face of the tiger.

Second verse.
\end{verse}
```

and would instead like to be able to write

```
\begin{verse}
There was a young lady of Niger
Who smiled as she rode on a tiger;
They returned from the ride
With the lady inside,
And the smile on the face of the tiger.

Second verse.
\end{verse}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's one possibility, using `\obeylines` and a variation of [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/107096/3954) to [Inserting automatic vertical space between blocks when \obeylines is active](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107071/3954) to redefine the standard `verse` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{verse}
  {\let\\\@centercr
    \list{}{\itemsep \z@
    \itemindent -1.5em
    \listparindent\itemindent
    \rightmargin \leftmargin
    \advance\leftmargin 1.5em}
    \item\relax\obeylines\begingroup\lccode`~=`\^^M
    \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\par\leavevmode}%
    \parskip=0pt plus 1pt%
  }
  {\endlist}
\makeatother               

\begin{document}

\begin{verse}
There was a young lady of Niger
Who smiled as she rode on a tiger;
They returned from the ride
With the lady inside,
And the smile on the face of the tiger.

Second verse.
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Great question and fantastic answer of Gonzalo Medina! Works fine!
A refinement for the current version of MiKTeX 2.9:

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{verse}[1][\linewidth]{%
    \stepcounter{verse@envctr}%
    \setcounter{poemline}{0}\refstepcounter{poemline}%
    \setcounter{vslineno}{1}%
    \let\\=\@vscentercr
    \list{}{\itemsep \z@
        \itemindent  -\vindent%
        \listparindent\itemindent
        \parsep       \stanzaskip
        \ifdim #1 < \linewidth
        \rightmargin        \z@
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{\linewidth}%
        \addtolength{\leftmargin}{-#1}%
        \addtolength{\leftmargin}{-0.5\leftmargin}%
        \else
        \rightmargin        \leftmargin
        \fi
        \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\vindent}}%
    \item\relax\obeylines\begingroup\lccode`~=`\^^M
    \lowercase{\endgroup\def~}{\par\leavevmode}%
    \parskip=0pt plus 1pt%
}
{\endlist}
\makeatother
```

Comment: What is LaTeX 2.9?