# Package xparse \SplitList last token

Tags: macros, expansion, xparse

I need to create a macro to render lists with a variable number of arguments (1+), e.g.
`\mylist{1,2,3}` should expand to `$\tilde{1}$--$\tilde{2}$--$\tilde{3}$`. I'm trying to use `xparse` and `\SplitList`, but I didn't find a way to tell when I'm processing the last token (where I don't need the separator `--`).

```
\NewDocumentCommand\mylist{>{\SplitList{,}}m}
{
  \ProcessList{#1}{\myitem}
}
\newcommand\myitem[1]{$\tilde{#1}$--}
```

This would expand `\mylist{1}` to `$\tilde{1}$--` instead of the desired `$\tilde{1}$`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Recognizing the first item is easier than the last.

There are many strategies for this.

1. Use a conditional

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{xparse}
   \NewDocumentCommand\mylist{>{\SplitList{,}}m}
   {%
     \ProcessList{#1}{\myitem}%
     \firstitemtrue
   }

   \newif\iffirstitem
   \firstitemtrue   
   \newcommand\myitem[1]{%
     \iffirstitem
       \firstitemfalse
     \else
       --%
     \fi
     $\tilde{#1}$}

   \begin{document}
   \mylist{a,b,c}
   \end{document}
   ```
2. Redefine the macro at first usage; doing the processing in a group will revert `\myitem` to the initial meaning.

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{xparse}
   \NewDocumentCommand\mylist{>{\SplitList{,}}m}
   {%
     {\ProcessList{#1}{\myitem}}%
   }

   \newcommand\myitem[1]{$\tilde{#1}$\let\myitem\myitema}
   \newcommand\myitema[1]{--$\tilde{#1}$}

   \begin{document}
   \mylist{a,b,c}
   \end{document}
   ```
3. Use a different approach with `expl3` macros, which is more flexible at the expense of some complication.

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{xparse}
   \ExplSyntaxOn
   \NewDocumentCommand\mylist{m}
    {
     \egreg_process_list:n {#1}
    }
   % define a sequence for storing the "massaged" items
   \seq_new:N \l_egreg_items_seq
   \cs_new_protected:Npn \egreg_process_list:n #1
    {
     % clear the sequence
     \seq_clear:N \l_egreg_items_seq
     % cycle through the arguments, storing "\tilde{<arg>}" in the sequence
     \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
      {
       \seq_put_right:Nn \l_egreg_items_seq { $\tilde{##1}$ }
      }
     % output the sequence putting "--" in between elements
     \seq_use:Nnnn \l_egreg_items_seq { -- } { -- } { -- }
    }
   \ExplSyntaxOff

   \begin{document}
   \mylist{a,b,c}
   \end{document}
   ```

The output in all three cases is

[image]

Note that you still need protecting end of lines with `%` in the body of `\NewDocumentCommand` unless you're in an `\ExplSyntaxOn` context.

Comment: An alternative to the `\clist_map_inline:nn` construction is to store the sequence with `\seq_set_split:Nnn <seq> { , }` (stable, doesn't ignore blank entries) or `\seq_set_from_clist:Nn <seq>` (experimental, ignores empty/blank entries), then using `\seq_set_map:NNn <seq> <seq> { \exp_not:n {$\tilde{##1}$} }` (experimental function), then `\seq_use:Nnnn` as you did.  It is more efficient :-), and (perhaps) clearer.

Answer (score 5):

I have used this trick often (see [Cunning (La)TeX tricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89187/5764)). The approach is to define a list separator using a "delay". That is, define it as a definition so that the first use just defines itself:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\NewDocumentCommand\mylist{O{--} >{\SplitList{,}}m}
{%
  \def\itemdelim{\def\itemdelim{#1}}% Define list separator with one delay
  \ProcessList{#2}{\myitem}% Process list
}
\newcommand\myitem[1]{\itemdelim$\tilde{#1}$}

\begin{document}
\mylist{a,b,c}
\end{document}
```

The additional optional argument to `\mylist` allows you to modify the list separator (or item delimiter) of the output. It defaults to `--`.