# Enumerate alignment

Tags: lists, vertical-alignment, enumerate

Is it possible to improve the alignment of the first item?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item  \begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}
   $x[n] = $ & \{1/3 & -1/2 & 1/4 & -1/8 & 1/6\} & and\\
      &   &   & $\uparrow$   &   &  &  \\   
  \end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}
   $h[n] = $ & \{1 & -1 & 1 & -1\} \\
             &    &   &    &   &    &    \\   
  \end{tabular}
\item \begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}
   $x[n] = $ & \{1 & -2 & -3 & 0 & -1\} & and\\  
  \end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}
   $h[n] = $ & \{2 & -1/2 & -3 & 1 & -2\} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: When you have a whole bunch of similarly-aligned `tabular` columns, use the `*{<num>}{<type>}` notation. In your case, `\begin{tabular}{*{10}{c}}`. It's easier to debug and more readable. Also, consider keeping the numerals in math mode, which provides a consistent spacing around the unary operator `-`.

Comment: What do you want the $\uparrow$ to point from and to?

Comment: The `\upparrow` is a "n = 0" mark.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to add `[t]` alignment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item  \begin{tabular}[t]{cccccccccc}        %%%% note [t] here.
   $x[n] = $ & \{1/3 & -1/2 & 1/4 & -1/8 & 1/6\} & and\\
      &   &   & $\uparrow$   &   &  &  \\
  \end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{cccccccccc}               %%%% and here.
   $h[n] = $ & \{1 & -1 & 1 & -1\} \\
             &    &   &    &   &    &    \\
  \end{tabular}
\item \begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}
   $x[n] = $ & \{1 & -2 & -3 & 0 & -1\} & and\\
  \end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccc}
   $h[n] = $ & \{2 & -1/2 & -3 & 1 & -2\} \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The following is a suggestion for a slightly easier notation that is more flexible. Moreover, it provides a consistent and accurate spacing around the math operators you use:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmath,xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand\printarray{O{~~} >{\SplitList{,}}m}
{%
  \def\itemdelim{\def\itemdelim{#1}}% Define list separator with one delay
  \ProcessList{#2}{\myitem}% Process list
}
\newcommand\myitem[1]{\itemdelim{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item $x[n] = \{\printarray{1/3,-1/2,\underset{\uparrow}{1/4},-1/8,1/6}\}$ and $h[n] = \{\printarray{1,-1,1,-1}\}$
  \item $x[n] = \{\printarray{1,-2,-3,0,-1}\}$ and $h[n] = \{\printarray{2,-1/2,-3,1,-2}\}$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The "array" is printed using `\printarray[<sep>]{<CSV list>}` where `<sep>` defaults to `~~`.

Delayed definition of the list separator stems from [Package xparse \SplitList last token](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/110898/5764) (or originally [Cunning (La)TeX tricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19746/5764)), while [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) provides `\underset`.

Answer (score 3):

I also would like to suggest you another approach, using a `matrix` environment instead of a `tabular`; it's more natural, gives you the desired vertical alignment automatically, and saves you the column format specification:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item 
$
x[n] = 
\{\begin{matrix} 
1/3 & -1/2 & \smash{\underset{\uparrow}{1/4}} & -1/8 & 1/6
\end{matrix}\} 
$\quad
and\quad 
$
h[n] =
\{\begin{matrix} 
1 & -1 & 1 & -1
\end{matrix}\}
$
\item 
$
x[n] = 
\{\begin{matrix}
1 & -2 & -3 & 0 & -1
\end{matrix}\}
$\quad
and\quad 
$
h[n] =
\{\begin{matrix}
2 & -1/2 & -3 & 1 & -2
\end{matrix}\}
$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it also applies math mode automatically, which makes the minus signs behave properly without having to think about them.

Answer (score 0):

This might be considered cheating, but if you skip the enumeration environment and put everything in one table, things behave better:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lcccccccccccccccccccc}
1.&$x[n]=$&\{1/3&-1/2&1/4&-1/8&1/6\}& and $h[n]=$&\{1&-1&1&-1\}\\
&&&&&$\uparrow$&&&&&&&&\\
2.&$x[n]=$&\{1&-2&-3&0&-1\}& and $h[n]=$&\{2&-1/2&-3&1&-2\}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]