# How to type permutations with commas a bit faster?

Tags: packages

Is it possible to use a package or something to make typing permutations a bit faster? I now have to type `$(a,b,c,d)$` in the best case, but I'd like to do something like `\Pm{a b c d}`. Can I do that?

Comment: You mean it puts the commas in automatically?  For me, there is no appreciable *speed* gain from typing `\pm{a b c d}` over `\pm{a,b,c,d}`.

Comment: @jon: Yes, I'd like the commas to be inserted automatically. Perhaps it's not that faster for a permutation with 4 elements, but I'm working with lots more, so in my opinion, it's a bit quicker when I don't have to type all the commas. By the way, it's typing `\pm{a b c d}`over `$(a,b,c,d)$`.

Comment: It should be noted that `\pm` is already used for `±`.

Comment: Naturally, I meant *after* defining a macro like `\newcommand\pm[1]{\ensuremath{(#1)}}` (and making sure I wasn't already competing with a definition for `\pm`)....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't seem much easier to type than $(a,b,c)$ but

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\pm#1{$(\xpm{}#1 ! )$}
\def\xpm#1#2 {\ifx!#2\else#1#2\expandafter\xpm\expandafter,\fi}

\begin{document}

\pm{a b c}

\end{document}
```

or without the space delimiter:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\pm#1{$(\xpm{}#1 ! )$}
\def\xpm#1#2{\ifx!#2\else#1#2\expandafter\xpm\expandafter,\fi}

\begin{document}

\pm{abc}

\pm{a{bc}de}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It would be shorter with a for loop and not type the space! `\pm{abcdefg}`, that is if the variables are single letters or add commas only if they are not `\pm{abcdefg,ze,xb}`

Comment: @YiannisLazarides you could just miss out the space after `#2` then it would iterate over single letter variables with no space needed.

Comment: One can delete the $-signs code in order to use `\pm` in a mathematical environment, like *displaymath*, *align**...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Was thinking about a for loop to capture the comma for the second case although maybe can be done with conditionals only.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides: It would be perfect if `\pm{a,bc,de}` would generate (a,bc,d,e)!

Comment: @Jeroen see update using the comma in input would be possible but seems weird to me in `a,bc,de` why `bc` one token but not `de` anyway `a{bc}de` is easier:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: You're absolutely right! I didn't think about that. Great piece of code!

Answer (score 5):

You can use a variant of my answer to [Permutation cycle notation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135868/permutation-cycle-notation)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\Pm}{ O{~} m O{,} }
 {
  (
  \jeroen_cycle:nnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
  )
 }

\seq_new:N \l_jeroen_cycle_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \jeroen_cycle:nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_jeroen_cycle_seq { #1 } { #2 }
  \seq_use:Nn \l_jeroen_cycle_seq { #3 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$\Pm{1 2 3}$

$\Pm[,]{1,2,3}[\;]$

$\Pm{1 2 3}[;]$

$\Pm[,]{1,2,3}$

$\Pm{1 2 3}[;]$
\end{document}
```

The leading optional argument is the input separator (default a space), the trailing one is the output separator (default a comma).

[image]

Alternatively, you can set up a key-value interface:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { jeroen/perms }
 {
  input-separator .tl_set:N   = \l_jeroen_perms_input_separator_tl,
  input-separator .initial:n  = { ~ },
  output-separator .tl_set:N  = \l_jeroen_perms_output_separator_tl,
  output-separator .initial:n = { , },
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\Pm}{ O{} m }
 {
  (
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { jeroen/perms } { #1 }
  \jeroen_cycle:n { #2 }
  \group_end:
  )
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\permset}{ m }
 {
  \keys_set:nn { jeroen/perms } { #1 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_jeroen_cycle_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \jeroen_cycle:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:NVn \l_jeroen_cycle_seq \l_jeroen_perms_input_separator_tl { #1 }
  \seq_use:NV \l_jeroen_cycle_seq \l_jeroen_perms_output_separator_tl
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { NV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_use:Nn { NV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$\Pm{1 2 3}$

$\Pm[output-separator=\;]{1 2 3}$

$\Pm[output-separator=;]{1 2 3}$

$\Pm[input-separator={,}]{1,2,3}$

\permset{output-separator=;}

$\Pm{1 2 3}$

\permset{input-separator=|}

$\Pm{1|2|3}$
\end{document}
```

Key-value pairs in the optional argument are local to the current permutation, while those in the `\permset` command are local to the group they appear in. It would be easy to extend this to also change the outer delimiters.

[image]