# Why don't \seq_put_right:Nx and \textsc play well together?

Tags: macros, expansion, xparse

(This question is somehow related to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110906/18401).)

I want to create a document command with an arbitrary number of (comma separated) parameters, each of them being a comma list, the items of which having to be processed.

The following MCE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\signature{m}
 {
  \__mymodule_process_list:n {#1}
 }
\seq_new:N \l__mymodule_items_seq
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mymodule_process_list:n #1
{
  \seq_clear:N \l__mymodule_items_seq
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {##1}
    \seq_get_right:NN \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_tl
    \seq_get_left:NN \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpb_tl
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__mymodule_items_seq {
    % \seq_put_right:NV \l__mymodule_items_seq {
      \l_tmpa_tl
      \c_space_tl \l_tmpb_tl
      % \c_space_tl \textsc{\l_tmpb_tl}
    }
  }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__mymodule_items_seq { ~ \& ~ }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\signature{
  {Last1, First1}
}

\signature{
  {Last1, First1},
  {Last2, First2}
}

\signature{
  {Last1, First1},
  {Last2, First2},
  {Last3, First3}
}
\end{document}
```

works well, that is, the result is:

```
First1 Last1
First1 Last1 & First2 Last2
First1 Last1 & First2 Last2 & First3 Last3
```

but, if I replace `\c_space_tl \l_tmpb_tl` by `\c_space_tl \textsc{\l_tmpb_tl}` in order to get the last names in small caps, LaTeX complains:

> ````
> ! Missing control sequence inserted.
>  <inserted text>
> \inaccessible ```
> ````

In this context, if I replace `\seq_put_right:Nx` by e.g. `\seq_put_right:NV`, the compilation goes smoothly, but the result isn't the expected one (same last name on each line):

```
First1 Lᴀꜱᴛ1
First1 Lᴀꜱᴛ2 & First2 Lᴀꜱᴛ2 
First1 Lᴀꜱᴛ3 & First2 Lᴀꜱᴛ3 & First3 Lᴀꜱᴛ3
```

With `\seq_put_right:Nx` and, instead of `\textsc{\l_tmpb_tl}`, `{\scshape \l_tmpb_tl}`, it works as expected but why doesn't it work with `\textsc{\l_tmpb_tl}`?

Comment: Try `\exp_not:N \textsc`

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Exactly! Sigh... expansion... ;) If you turn your comment into a n answer I could accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to prevent the expansion of `\textsc` (or any other macro that should not expand) with `\exp_not:N`, so

```latex
\seq_put_right:Nx \l__mymodule_items_seq
  { \c_space_tl \exp_not:N \textsc { \l_tmpb_tl } }
%               ^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

Your usage of the `NV` variant is wrong.  The `V`-type is supposed to take a *single variable* as argument, so this would be correct:

```latex
\seq_put_right:NV \l__mymodule_items_seq \l_tmpb_tl
```

this would be a slightly weird syntax (though not necessarily wrong):

```latex
\seq_put_right:NV \l__mymodule_items_seq { \l_tmpb_tl }
```

and this is completely off

```latex
\seq_put_right:NV \l__mymodule_items_seq { \l_tmpa_tl \l_tmpb_tl }
```

---

`\scshape` works (after `\begin{document}`) because it is defined with `\protected`.  If you do `\ShowCommand\scshape`, you will see `\scshape=\protected macro:->[...]`, so it does not expand in `\edef` (used by the `x` expansion in `\seq_put_right:Nx`).

`\textsc`, on the other hand, is a `robust` macro (`\ShowCommand\textsc`):

```latex
> \textsc=robust macro:
->\protect \textsc  .

> \textsc =\long macro:
#1->[...]
```

so it breaks inside an `\edef` (it would need `\protected@edef` to not explode).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\exp_not:N \textsc`, but tokens in the names could bomb as well. I suggest wrapping with `\text_expand:n` the parts were textual input might contain dangerous tokens.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand\signature{m}
 {
  \__mymodule_process_list:n {#1}
 }

\seq_new:N \l__mymodule_items_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__mymodule_process_list:n #1
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__mymodule_items_seq
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
   {
    \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {##1}
    \seq_get_right:NN \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpa_tl
    \seq_get_left:NN \l_tmpb_seq \l_tmpb_tl
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__mymodule_items_seq
     {
      \text_expand:n { \l_tmpa_tl \c_space_tl \textsc { \l_tmpb_tl } }
     }
   }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__mymodule_items_seq { ~ \& ~ }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\signature{
  {Last1, First1}
}

\signature{
  {Last1, First1},
  {Last2, First2}
}

\signature{
  {Last1, First1},
  {Last2, First2},
  {La\'st3, F\'irst3}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Tokens in the names seem to be harmless in case `{ \scshape \l_tmpb_tl }` is used instead of `\textsc { \l_tmpb_tl }`, isn't it?