A blank space or character after a reference when using kaobook (biblatex) sidecite, but no space anywhere in the text nor in the used library
I have a fallowing blank space after \sidecite citation (the one before the dot and after ciation),

even though there is no space defined anywhere.
The sidecite in the kaobook is defined as:
% Command to print a citation in the margins
\NewDocumentCommand{\sidecite}{m}{% The parameter is the citation key
        \cite{#1}% With this we print the marker in the text and add the item to the bibliography at the end
        \margincitation{#1}% We then pass the cited items to this command, \margincitation
}

When I put any text in front of \cite{#1}, e.g. \cite{#1}TEXT I get the citation, the text and the blank space, like this: [104]TEXT .. So it does not come from cite itself.
Furthermore, if I use \cite alone, it does not leave this space. But there is nothing more beside the \cite{#1} in the \sidecite, that prints the citation key.  So I can't figure out from where the blank space comes from.
I paste the rest of the kaobook bibliography library below:
%% kaobiblio.sty
%% Copyright 2020 Federico Marotta
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
% The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
% version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work is Federico Marotta
%
% This work consists of all the files listed in MANIFEST.md.

\ProvidesPackage{styles/kaobiblio}

\RequirePackage{etoolbox} % Easy programming to modify TeX stuff
%\RequirePackage{calc} % Operations like sums and differences
%\RequirePackage{marginnote} % Provides options for margin notes
\RequirePackage{perpage} % Reset counters
\RequirePackage{xkeyval} % Manage class options
\RequirePackage{xparse} % Parse arguments for macros
\RequirePackage{xstring} % Parse strings
\RequirePackage{hyperref} % Required for hyperlinks

% Choose the default options, which will be overwritten by the options passed to this package.
\PassOptionsToPackage{
    %style=numeric-comp,
    %citestyle=authortitle-icomp,
    citestyle=numeric-comp,
    %bibstyle=authoryear,
    bibstyle=numeric,
    sorting=none,
    %sorting=nyt,
    %sortcites=true,
    %autocite=footnote,
    backend=biber, % Compile the bibliography with biber
    hyperref=true,
    backref=true,
    citecounter=true,
    citetracker=true,
    ibidtracker=context,
}{biblatex}

% Pass this package's options to biblatex, overwriting the previous settings.
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{biblatex}}

% Process the options
\ProcessOptions\relax

% Load biblatex
\RequirePackage{biblatex}

% Remove some unwanted entries from the bibliography
\AtEveryBibitem{
    \clearfield{issn}
    \clearfield{isbn}
    \clearfield{archivePrefix}
    \clearfield{arxivId}
    \clearfield{pmid}
    \clearfield{eprint}
    \ifentrytype{online}{}{\ifentrytype{misc}{}{\clearfield{url}}}
    \ifentrytype{book}{\clearfield{doi}}{}
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   BACK REFERENCES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Check if a string is in a comma-separated list
\newcommand\IfStringInList[2]{\IfSubStr{,#2,}{,#1,}}

% Set the back reference strings
\IfStringInList{english}{\bbl@loaded}{
    \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{%
        backrefpage = {cited on page},
        backrefpages = {cited on pages},
    }
}{}
\IfStringInList{italian}{\bbl@loaded}{
    \DefineBibliographyStrings{italian}{%
        backrefpage = {citato a pag.},
        backrefpages = {citato a pagg.},
    }
}{}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CITATION COMMANDS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

%\newlength\sclen

% Command to print a citation in the margins
%\NewDocumentCommand{\sidecite}{O{0pt}m}{% The optional parameter is the vertical shift; the mandatory one is the citation key
%   \cite{#2}% With this we print the marker in the text and add the item to the bibliography at the end
%   \margincitation[#1]{#2}% We then pass the cited items to this command, \margincitation
%}
% Command to print a citation in the margins
\NewDocumentCommand{\sidecite}{m}{% The parameter is the citation key
    \cite{#1}% With this we print the marker in the text and add the item to the bibliography at the end
    \margincitation{#1}% We then pass the cited items to this command, \margincitation
}



% Command to split the cited items and execute an action for each of them
\newcommand\margincitedelim{\\} % Choose the default separator for multiple citations
\NewDocumentCommand{\margincitation}{o >{\SplitList{,}}m}{% The mandatory parameter is a comma-separated list of citation keys, which is splitted into single items
    % Redefine the \margincitedelim with a delay (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110898/package-xparse-splitlist-last-token). Users can 'renew' the \margincitedelim command in their main.tex.
    \let\origmargincitedelim\margincitedelim
    \renewcommand\margincitedelim{\renewcommand\margincitedelim{\origmargincitedelim}}
    \marginnote[#1]{\ProcessList{#2}{\formatmargincitation}}% Create a marginnote for each item
    \let\margincitedelim\origmargincitedelim% Reset
}
% Command to format the marginnote created for cited items
\NewDocumentCommand{\formatmargincitation}{m}{% The parameter is a single citation key
    \margincitedelim\parencite{#1}: \citeauthor*{#1} (\citeyear{#1}), \citetitle{#1}\\%
}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   CITATION ENVIRONMENTS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% TODO: create a fancy environment for this. Perhaps printing also the
% abstract.

% Cite commands (assuming biblatex is loaded)
\DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite}{%
    \defcounter{maxnames}{99}%
    \usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\clearfield{url}%
    \clearfield{pages}%
    \clearfield{pagetotal}%
    \clearfield{edition}%
    \clearfield{issn}%
    \clearfield{doi}%
    \usedriver
    {\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{default}}
    {\thefield{entrytype}}
}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}


There is no compilable code here, so I can't test if this really solves the problem, but there are several places where the shown code introduces unwanted white space. Most notably in \DeclareCiteCommand{\fullcite} the closing curly brace before the {\multicitedelim} should be moved to the end of the previous line so that that line reads {\thefield{entrytype}}}.

All line ends in the \AtEveryBibitem{ block should also be "hidden" with % to avoid unwanted space in the bibliography, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/35864. (But then again it's possible that the biblatex features that avoid undesirable space help you there and get rid of these unwanted spaces so that you won't see a difference.)

Tried both, and it does change the anything.
The problems seems to be very difficult to spot, even though it should fully explainable by \cite argument. Furthermore, normal \cite work perfectly well

OK, then I really need to see compilable code that is a small as possible, yet still reproduces the undesirable behaviour.

you are adding a space here \renewcommand\margincitedelim{\renewcommand\margincitedelim{\origmargincitedelim}}
