# Display bracket and a text line in the same line

Tags: lists, enumerate

I want to get the  following :

[image]

For this I have used the the following code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item
\item Second item
\end{enumerate}
[Hint:
\begin{enumerate}
 \item Hint for first item
 \item Hint for Second item
\end{enumerate}]
\end{document}
```

which produces :
[image]

How can I do the exact result which I want ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know whether you're up for suggestions, but here's one:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{hintcntr}
%\renewcommand{\thehintcntr}{\arabic{hintcntr}}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{hints}
  {% \begin{hints}
    \setcounter{hintcntr}{0}% Restart numbering
    \renewcommand{\item}{\stepcounter{hintcntr}\@ifstar\@itemstar\@itemnostar}
    \def\@itemstar{\ignorespaces}% \item*
    \def\@itemnostar{\ignorespaces\thehintcntr.~}% \item
    \par%
    [~Hint:%
  }
  {\unskip~]}% \end{hints}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First item
  \item Second item
  \item Third item
  \item Last item
\end{enumerate}
\begin{hints}
 \item Hint for first item in list
 \item Hint for second item in list
 \item*% no hint here
 \item Hint for last item in list
\end{hints}
\end{document}
```

The `hints` environment sets a regular paragraph with `\item` printing the next hint, while `\item*` just steps the hint counter without printing anything.

---

Here's an implementation of the `hints` environment that matches in output what you're currently requesting:

[image]

```
\newcounter{hintcntr}
%\renewcommand{\thehintcntr}{\arabic{hintcntr}}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{hints}
  {% \begin{hints}
    \setcounter{hintcntr}{0}% Restart numbering
    \def\newpar{\def\newpar{\par}}% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89187/5764
    \renewcommand{\item}{\stepcounter{hintcntr}\@ifstar\@itemstar\@itemnostar}
    \def\@itemstar{\ignorespaces}% \item*
    \def\@itemnostar{\ignorespaces\newpar\noindent\thehintcntr.~}% \item
    \par\noindent%
    [~Hint:%
  }
  {\unskip~]}% \end{hints}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you @Werner for your great cooperation. My problem is solved, and +1 for you.

Answer (score 8):

Another option would be to use the [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package with its `inline` option and an `enumerate*` for the inner list. A new list can be easily set to produce the desired output:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\newlist{hint}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[hint,1]{label=\arabic*.}
\newenvironment{hints}
  {[Hint:~\begin{hint}}
  {\end{hint}]}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First item
\item Second item
\end{enumerate}
\begin{hints}
 \item Hint for first item \\
 \item Hint for Second item
\end{hints}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @G.M. it shows 5 errors like : Unknown option `inline' for package `enumitem',
Missing number, treated as zero\item. What are these?

Comment: @SoumitraSen you are using an outdated version of `enumitem`. Please update the package.