# References as text decorations (using multiple files)

Tags: tikz-pgf, cross-referencing, text-decorations, document-configuration

I would like to draw a picture in which a line connects two points. Along this line, there should be a text "x", where x is the number of a specific equation in another document. Unfortunately, I am not able to realize this idea. So far, I have a main document (`main.tex`) and a figure document (`figure.tex`). I first compile `main.tex`, then I compile `figure.tex`. Using references as node labels in the figure seems fine. However, for text decorations they seem to totally lock up the pdflatex application. Here is a minimum working example:

`main.tex`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}

% the equation of interest
\begin{equation} \label{x}
  x = 42
\end{equation}

% the figure of interest
\includegraphics{figure.pdf}

\end{document}
```

`figure.tex`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xr} % edit: this line and the next allow for cross-referencing
\externaldocument{main}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[] (0,0) node[] (A) {\ref{x}}; % this works
\draw[] (1,1) node[] (B) {x};       % this also works

\draw[decoration={text along path,text align={align=center},%
text={\ref{x}}},postaction={decorate}] (A) -- (B); % does not compile, i. e., pdflatex seems to be in an infinite loop

\draw[decoration={text along path,text align={align=center},%
text={x}},postaction={decorate}] (A) -- (B); % does compile, but is useless

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So my questions are as follows:

**1.) (Solved?)** How do I have to configure the compiling procedure to be able to use references from `main.tex` in `figure.tex`? Ideally, I would like to use externalization to produce the figures in `figure.tex`. This is my motivation for using two different files in the first place.
**Edit:** I think I can answer this question for myself now using [the answer to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14364/cross-referencing-between-different-files): By adding

```
\usepackage{xr} \externaldocument{main}
```

to `figure.tex`, referencing from `figure.tex` to `main.tex` should work! If this should be a bad style, please correct me. Question 2 remains unsolved though.

**2.) How can I use a reference as a text decoration? I have no idea why this fails.**

Comment: Why do you think you need to put the figure in a separate file in order to use externalisation? Have you tried using the `external` TiKZ library?

Comment: You can't put \ref and \label in two different documents.  You might try \hypertarget and \href instead.

Comment: With or without `xr` package, `\ref{x}` is expanded to `1\hbox {}` that is not a correct content for `text along path`.

Comment: .. so instead of `\ref`, use `\getrefnumber` from `refcount` package (cf. [How to compare the output of \ref to a number?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/224950/14500)).

Answer (score 3):

With or without the `xr` package, `\ref{x}` is expanded to `1\hbox {}` that is not a correct content for `text along path`.

To get exactly `1`, you may use the `\getrefnumber` macro provided by the `refcount` package (cf. [How to compare the output of \ref to a number?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/224950/14500)).

Here is a working `figure.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{refcount}
\usepackage{xr} % edit: this line and the next allow for cross-referencing
\externaldocument{main}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[] (0,0) node[] (A) {\ref{x}};
  \draw[] (1,1) node[] (B) {x}; 

  \draw[postaction={
    decoration={text along path,text align={align=center},
      text={\getrefnumber{x}}},decorate}]
  (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first question has been solved using `xr` package, as long as `main.aux` is in the same folder as `figure.tex`. For the second question, you can (ab-)use the `character command` key as follows.

First, you need the key `text effects along path`, so that each character is inserted in the picture as a TikZ node. Then use `text effects/.cd` to enable access to keys customizing text effects, in particular, the `character command` key. We define a macro `\mycommand` as `\def\mycommand#1{\ref{#1}}` to be used with this key. The `character command=\mycommand` key expands the TeX macro `\mycommand` taking each character in `text={x}` as its argument. In this case, there's only one character `x`, and so `\mycommand{x}` expands to `\ref{x}`. [If your label has more than one character, the same trick applies, but you'll need to add the key `group letters`, so that a string of letters are treated as one "character".]

## Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,mathtools}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{x}
  a^2=b^2+c^2 
\end{equation}

\def\mycommand#1{\ref{#1}} % define character command

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[] (0,0) node[] (A) {\ref{x}}; % this works
\draw[] (1,1) node[] (B) {x};       % this also works

\draw[decoration={
    text effects along path,                          % new
    text align={center},
    text={x},
    text effects/.cd,                                 % new
    text along path,                                  % new
    group letters,                                    % new
    every word/.style={character command=\mycommand}  % new
  },
  postaction={decorate}
] (A) -- (B); 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]