# Minimum and maximum label values

Tags: macros

I was wondering if there is some LaTeX macro/command (I don't know the exact term) that, given a list of labels, gives the lowest/largest label value and has the same behaviour as `\ref{}` (i.e., inserting a hyperlink to the referenced object in the pdf).

Consider the following simple example, in which are defined 4 different equations.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:energy_mass_lightspeed}
E = mc^2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:basic_arithmetics}
2 + 2 = 4
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:pythagorean_theorem}
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:handshaking_lemma}
\sum_{v\in V(G)} d_G(u) = 2|E(G)|
\end{equation}

In the following sections we use Equations from 
\firstlabel{eq:energy_mass_lightspeed,eq:basic_arithmetics,eq:pythagorean_theorem,eq:handshaking_lemma}
to 
\lastlabel{eq:energy_mass_lightspeed,eq:basic_arithmetics,eq:pythagorean_theorem,eq:handshaking_lemma}.

\end{document}
```

In the last four lines of the example the hypothetical macros `\firstlabel`and `\lastlabel` have as parameter a list of labels (the labels of the four equations). The first, `\minimumlabel{..}`, should have the same behaviour (in this case) as `\ref{eq:energy_mass_lightspeed}` since `eq:energy_mass_lightspeed` is the label that is defined first. The second, `\lastlabel{..}`, should have the same behaviour  as `\ref{eq:handshaking_lemma}` since `eq:handshaking_lemma` is the label that is defined last.

**Question** Can this be done? If so, does there exist something like this?

The motivation is that sometimes the equations can be rearranged in a document in order to enhance readability, or even to be able to streamline explanations. If, then, the writer wants to refer to an equation range, they could use the first and last labels at the moment of referring to the range, but that can change in a future modification of the document. Writing the numbers of the equations is not an option since the authors may decide to add more equations before the first, thus changing the number of the equations. Command `\vrefrange` [helps a bit](https://texblog.org/2017/12/17/fancy-labels-and-references-in-latex/) but it needs the parameters to always be the first and the last (notice that equations may be reordered at some point).

Comment: Well it should be possible, but LaTeX package authors usually only expose the "common cases" in the API so you may expect to have to hack around a bit if they don't have suitable API

Comment: Okay [cross referencing - How to compare the output of \ref to a number? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224950/how-to-compare-the-output-of-ref-to-a-number)

Comment: There is the package [cleveref](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref). Quote from the description at [https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref): *The package also offers a means of referencing a list of references, each formatted according to its type. **In such lists, it can collapse sequences of numerically-consecutive labels to a reference range.***

Comment: The easiest solution is to simply look at the aux file.  Every \label shows up as \newlabel wit the \ref{} text  and the page number.  Using hypertext, the arguments also include the counter name and the \hypertarget name.

Comment: @UlrichDiez, thank you for your comment. That really helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, a solution is to use the package [`cleveref`](https://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref). In order to do what I asked in the post, first include the package

```
\usepackage{cleveref}
```

and use the appropriate command in the last sentence of the document

```
In the following sections we use \cref{eq:energy_mass_lightspeed,eq:handshaking_lemma,eq:basic_arithmetics,eq:pythagorean_theorem}.
```

Notice that the labels are not given to `\cref` in the order they were defined. The command above produces

```
In the following sections we use eqs. (1) to (4).
```

Two interesting options are `capitalize` and `noabbrev` which, when passed to the package

```
\usepackage[capitalize,noabbrev]{cleveref}
```

the command above will produce

```
In the following sections we use Equations (1) to (4).
```

(Notice that it went from `eqs.` to `Equations`).