# Symbol inbetween "#" and "ff"

Tags: symbols, math-operators, stacking-symbols

I wondered how to create a symbol that looks like "#" (for connected sum) and "ff" for "fiber". The size and angles should be like the "#", but the vertical bars should look like two f`s. Another way to describe it would be a fortissimo symbol with two bars.

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/71/Music-fortissimo.png

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, I introduce `\varhash` and `\varfhash` to be used in tandem (or for sans font, `\sfvarhash` and `\sfvarfhash`).  I started with a `\sffamily` `f` to build things from there.  In the last line, I overlay the two glyphs to see if they compare.

Since I use the current font for the `f`, this answer will depend on the font chosen for the document.  Bu the answer can be tailored to suit.

EDITED to provide both sans and roman versions.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][.5]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
%%%%%% SF ITSHAPE VERSION
\def\sfvarfhash{%
  \stackinset{c}{}{b}{1.5pt}{\rule{1.45ex}{\sfrlthk}\kern1pt}{%
  \stackinset{c}{}{b}{3.7pt}{\rule{1.45ex}{\sfrlthk}\kern1pt}{%
    \textsf{\itshape ff}%
  }}%
}
\def\sfvarhash{%
  \kern1pt%
  \stackinset{c}{}{b}{1.5pt}{\rule{1.45ex}{\sfrlthk}\kern1pt}{%
  \stackinset{c}{}{b}{3.7pt}{\rule{1.45ex}{\sfrlthk}\kern1pt}{%
    \slantbox[.2]{\mysfrule\kern2pt\mysfrule\kern2.3pt}%
  }}%
  \kern1pt%
}
\def\sfrlthk{.17ex}
\def\mysfrule{\rule{\sfrlthk}{1.4ex}}
%%%%%% RM ITSHAPE VERSION
\def\varfhash{%
  \kern -1.5pt%
  \stackinset{c}{}{c}{-1.7pt}{\kern1pt\rule{1.7ex}{\rlthk}}{%
  \stackinset{c}{}{c}{1.7pt}{\kern1pt\rule{1.7ex}{\rlthk}}{%
    \kern2pt\itshape ff\kern2pt%
  }}%
}
\def\varhash{%
  \kern-.5pt%
  \stackinset{c}{}{c}{-1.7pt}{\kern1pt\rule{1.7ex}{\rlthk}}{%
  \stackinset{c}{}{c}{1.7pt}{\kern1pt\rule{1.7ex}{\rlthk}}{%
    \kern2pt\kern.2pt\slantbox[.2]{\myrule\kern2.4pt\myrule}\kern.2pt\kern2pt%
  }}%
  \kern1pt%
}
\def\rlthk{.13ex}
\def\myrule{\rule[-.33ex]{\rlthk}{1.8ex}}
\begin{document}
\sfvarfhash\sfvarhash\par
\ooalign{z\sfvarhash x\cr z\sfvarfhash x} overlaid\par
\varfhash\varhash\par
\ooalign{z\varhash x\cr z\varfhash x} overlaid\par
\par \# for comparison
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is a version with `\int` instead of `f`, which allows more flexibility with the placement of the horizontal bars:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx}
\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][.5]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
%%%%%% RM ITSHAPE VERSION
\def\varfhash{%
  \kern-4.1pt%
  \stackinset{c}{}{c}{-1.4pt}{\kern1pt\rule{1.6ex}{\rlthk}}{%
  \stackinset{c}{}{c}{1.4pt}{\kern1pt\rule{1.6ex}{\rlthk}}{%
    \kern3.1pt${\int}\kern-4pt{\int}$\kern2.1pt%
  }}%
  \kern-2.2pt%
}
\def\varhash{%
  \kern-.7pt%
  \stackinset{c}{}{c}{-1.4pt}{\kern.5pt\rule{1.6ex}{\rlthk}}{%
  \stackinset{c}{}{c}{1.4pt}{\kern.5pt\rule{1.6ex}{\rlthk}}{%
    \kern2.4pt\slantbox[.09]{\myrule\kern2.1pt\myrule}\kern2.4pt%
  }}%
  \kern.6pt%
}
\def\rlthk{.16ex}
\def\myrule{\rule[-.23ex]{\rlthk}{1.6ex}}
\begin{document}
$\varfhash\varhash$\par
$x\varfhash y\varhash z$\par
\ooalign{z\varhash x\cr z\varfhash x} overlaid\par
\par \# for comparison
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think it is pretty good. I just had in mind, that it is like a "f" at the upper and lower end (as in the wikimedia picture). And maybe a little less bold, but that would be just an extra.

Comment: @Zonan Please see revision.

Comment: Ah, now I understand why you put the vertical bars so far apart: In order to cover the f' s bar. Is there a way to avoid the f' s bar? I guess the integral solution below. Otherwise I´ll just lift the lower bar of the "fiber connected sum"

Comment: @Zonan If I use the `f` then one is stuck with the vertical placement of the bar.  I suppose one could craft the answer in terms of `\int`, using a similar approach, with flexibility in the offset values of the `\stackinset` terms.  Of course, if one uses the `\int`, the vertical slant will change.

Comment: @Zonan I have added a version with the `\int`, though I still think I prefer the italic `f` version.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this would be to use the double integral math symbol and strike it out.

```
\usepackage{ulem,amsmath,xspace}
\newcommand{\fiber}{\sout{$\iint$}\xspace}
```

And then use `\fiber` where needed. It's far from ideal, but it can do the trick.