# How to check for more elements a foreach loop?

Tags: conditionals, loops, foreach

I want to check if there are more elements in a foreach loop. How can this be done?

This is an example for loop:

```
\foreach \p/\q in {a/{1,2,3}, b/{4,5,6}}
    \foreach \r in \q { (\r) }
```

**EDIT#1**

An example of code in a programming language for what I want to achieve would be:

```
a = [3,4,5,6]
for i, val in enumerate(a):
    print(val, sep='', end='')
    if i < len(a)-1:
        print(',', sep='', end='')
```

Hope that helps to clarify.

Comment: Since it seems such a big issue, when I mention that I want to use the template for pandoc and that there is pandoc's extending syntax in it, I'll reword the whole thing into something much simpler.

Comment: The question here seems rather different to the initial one. I've therefore reopened and removed what are now 'stale' comments.

Comment: @JosephWright: With all due respect, an answer to this question would've been an answer to the other question as well. Ofc everyone is entitled to their own opinion. Thanks for taking care of things.

Comment: I don't see that (the earlier version did not use `\foreach` or even mention `pgf`), but I am pleased you now have a useful answer.

Comment: Hm... I have no clue what is actually asked here and how the question fits the answer (or vice versa). Maybe you can rephrase your question with the intended output? Even if your problem is solved now, it would help others with a similar problem.

Comment: Not sure if you're still interested, but as mentioned in a previous comment of mine, adding `$sep$` just before the `\and` in your Pandoc template seems to do the job. At least, that worked with my simple test.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: Yes that would have been an accepted answer on the question. Now I removed that context of pandoc. It seems if I accepted this as an answer, it would be pandoc specific. If there was a pandoc stack exchange, I'd have asked the question there and accepted your solution as an answer : ) However, I thought I easily do it with plain latex as well. Turned out to be a bit more difficult, but here we are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `count` feature of `\foreach`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}

\foreach \i [count=\xi] in {a,b,c}
 {
  \ifnum\xi>1 and \fi \i
 }

\foreach \i [count=\xi] in {a}
 {
  \ifnum\xi>1 and \fi \i
 }

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So it's rather a foreach and an added counter. That makes sense.

Comment: Wouldn't it have to be `\and`? Seems I can't use your code within the `\author{}` braces, it causes a warning: `Runaway argument?
{ \foreach \i [count=\xi ] in {AuthorName, Intitute, Germa\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \author was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.32 No pages of output.`

Comment: This answer works with a simple foreach, but will it work with the example from the question? As in, a list within the elements of the foreach?

Comment: @Alenanno I can't read the OP's mind and there is *no* workable example in the question.

Comment: @Zelphir People can't read your mind.

Comment: @egreg I meant, if there's a foreach list like `a/{1,2,3}, b/{4,5,6,7}`, can you make it tell you: `a has 3 elements, b has 4`?

Comment: @Alenanno Yes, of course you can, by doing `\xdef\something{\xi}` at each step, so when the `\foreach` ends, you can examine the meaning of `\something`. You can't do it in advance, though, so a double `\foreach` is needed.

Comment: @egreg Is that command supposed to be inside the `\foreach`? Ah ok. :)

Comment: @egreg: So you are saying, that the language construct of a foreach loop in Latex is not usable everywhere in the Latex code the same way? Or what did you mean by "people can't read your mind"? A little bit of explanation please!

Comment: @Zelphir You give no sensible use case; and I'm afraid the edit doesn't clarify.

Comment: @egreg removed the use case, because everyone got hung up at the word pandoc and overlooked (or didn't care) that this can be done in pure Latex, not minding what kind of tool I used later on. So I made the question more general, only talking about Latex foreach. Now you're telling me you want the use case. This could in its current form serve well as some kind of "wiki" or "howto" post, becaues it should be use case independent.

Comment: @Zelphir LaTeX is a document syntax. Much of the programming stuff is either done in TeX or by using add-on packages. The latter tend to have particular specialisms. You've picked `\foreach` from `pgf` so the answer here quite reasonably uses it. If you want to do something different _you need to explain_. In particular, it sounds like you've tried to use `\foreach` in an expansion context, which if you provide a full example will be obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [a cunning (La)TeX trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89187/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\printlist}[2][,]{%
  \def\itemdelim{\def\itemdelim{#1}}% Item delimiter delayed by one cycle
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\itemdelim##1}% How each item is processed
  \docsvlist{#2}}% Process CSV list

\begin{document}

\printlist{a,b,c}

\printlist[ and ]{a,b,c}

\printlist{}

\printlist{a}

\end{document}
```

The approach is to always print a separator, but the first is only a redefinition of the separator, actually printing nothing.