# Problems getting \expandafter\<controlsequence>\endgroup to work as expected

Tags: expansion, grouping

I have a scenario where I'm testing for a condition within a group which will then trigger inputting a corresponding outside file.  The problem is that the outside file may contain control sequences that I later need.  I tried to make sure the expansion was going to happen after closing the group as in the following example. (I've omitted the testing condition because this example nevertheless duplicates my error.)

```
\begin{filecontents}{anotherfile}
\def\aemoon{This is the moon}
This is my other file.
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Testing

\begingroup
  \def\helloworld{\input{anotherfile}}
  \expandafter\helloworld
\endgroup

\aemoon

\end{document}
```

But this results in an error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.17 \aemoon
```

The same thing happens below where there's no need to input an outside file

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Testing

\begingroup
  \def\helloworld{\newcommand\aemoon{this is the moon}}
  \expandafter\helloworld
\endgroup

\aemoon

\end{document}
```

In either example, I was expecting that the command `\aemoon` was getting defined outside of the group on account of `\expandafter`.  (`\aftergroup` will clearly not work since after the group `\helloworld` has not been defined.)

Thinking back to my original situation where I'm inputting another file, I know I could write something like

```
\begin{filecontents}{anotherfile}
\def\aemoon{This is the moon}
This is my other file.
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Testing

\begingroup
  \gdef\helloworld{\input{anotherfile}}
\endgroup
\helloworld

\aemoon

\end{document}
```

So, I do have a work around.  But I would like to know why the first two examples are not working because my understanding is that the expansion should be happening outside the group, but...

So, what is happening here?

Comment: I'm not sure what would be the reason for the group. Can you think of one?

Comment: @egreg In this MWE there's no need except to create the situation I'm facing.  In the real deal, I'm doing a number of tests etc. and defining a number of temporary control sequences for this and that for which I felt a group was the ideal way to proceed.  But then I needed a way of getting some information out of the group in a context where definitions may not be global.

Comment: Be careful that with Hood Chatham's (good) technique, you only get the first level expansion of `\helloworld` and then the group ends, destroying all assignments made inside it. So, if you say `\begingroup\ifbla\def\foo{bla}\else\def\foo{bar}\fi\def\gnu{A \foo}\expandafter\endgroup\gnu` you'll be in trouble.

Comment: @egreg Good point.  Nothing of the sort will happen since mostly the machinations inside the group are to determine which file to input.

Comment: Remark, this is a TeX idiom https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19750/250119

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should say:

```
\begingroup
  \def\helloworld{\newcommand\aemoon{this is the moon}}
  \expandafter
\endgroup\helloworld
```

The idea here is that the `\expandafter` causes `\helloworld` to be expanded before TeX sees the `\endgroup`, so first `\helloworld` gets expanded and TeX sees `\endgroup\newcommand\aemoon{this is the moon}`. Then it evaluates the `\endgroup` and `\helloworld` goes out of scope, then it evaluates the `\newcommand` and `\aemoon` is defined.

You probably confused this situation with the case where there's a command in a conditional that takes an argument, and you don't want it to use `\fi` or `\else` and the false clause as its argument so you say: `\ifsomething \expandafter\somecommand\fi`. Since `\else` and `\fi` are fully expandable and when expanded delete themselves (and in the case of `\else` the false clause), this fixes that problem.

The problem with saying `\expandafter\helloworld\endgroup` is that `\endgroup` is not expandable, so the result is the `\expandafter` expands the `\endgroup`, which changes it not at all -- `\endgroup` acts like a `}` here. Then what TeX sees is `\mycommand\endgroup`, which doesn't do what you want.

Roughly speaking, TeX has two stages of evaluation -- expansion, where it takes macros and repeatedly expands them, and evaluation, where it takes unexpandable primitives (either characters or commands like `\bgroup`, `\relax`, `\def`, `\show` etc) and evaluates them. `\expandafter` only interacts with the expansion stage. Many nonintuitive behaviors of TeX result from this expansion evaluation distinction.

However, even if `\expandafter\helloworld\egroup` did behave as you expected, it would not be right, because that would then be the same as saying `\egroup\helloworld`, which would cause an error because the definition of `\helloworld` went out of scope.

Comment: Very nice.  This is a solution.  But, it still leaves my question unanswered.  Why is `\expandafter\helloworld\endgroup` not doing what I think it should be?

Comment: That is definitely the case I was thinking of.

Comment: I'll try to add a bit more detail as to why they are different -- it's actually quite subtle and confusing.

Answer (score 7):

`\endgroup` is not expandable, which makes

```
\begingroup
  \def\helloworld{\newcommand\aemoon{this is the moon}}
  \expandafter\helloworld
\endgroup
```

equivalent to

```
\begingroup
  \def\helloworld{\newcommand\aemoon{this is the moon}}
  \helloworld
\endgroup
```

As such, `\helloworld` is defined, executed and then everything within the group that isn't `\global` does not survive. This includes `\aemoon`. You may consider an alternative

```
\begingroup
  \def\helloworld{\endgroup\newcommand\aemoon{this is the moon}}
  \helloworld
```

where `\helloworld` ends the group *implicitly*, leaving `\aemoon` still defined.

Comment: Hmmm.  I like this approach.

Comment: @A.Ellett: The approach is similar to the commonly-used `\begingroup \edef\x{\endgroup <xxx>}\x` technique to expand `<xxx>` but not keep the definition of `\x`.

Comment: which is exactly why I like it so much

Answer (score 5):

```
   \expandafter\helloworld\endgroup
```

applies `\expandafter` to `\endgroup` that is not an error but it does nothing as `\endgroup` is not expandable so it is equivalent to

```
  \helloworld\endgroup
```

So  `\helloworld` acting inside the group is the expected behaviour.