# Checking if current item is last item inside enumerated list

Tags: lists, enumitem

I have a personalized class for exams and I need to do something different before the end of my custom enumerated list (questions).

After each question I add a new blank page with some text at the top (such as "(question X, cont'd)", and then start the next question on a new page -- so question 1 is on the first page, page 2 is blank except for some text on the top, and question 2 is on the third page.  But for the last question I don't want to add the extra page for the next question (there is no next question).

Is there a way of doing this without manually adding the `\newpage`?  That is, can I code this inside the custom enumerated list, so that if I change the order of the questions I won't have to keep changing the information?

I am already using the `enumitem` package, but can't find an option to check if current item is the last item (even if compiled more than once).

What I have right now (simplified):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Questions:

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \label{qa} This is a question.
    \newpage
    (Question \ref{qa}, cont'd)
    \newpage
  \item \label{qb} Another question.
    \newpage
    (Question \ref{qb}, cont'd)
    \newpage
  \item \label{qc} Final question.  Note that there is only one "newpage" after it.
    \newpage
    (Question \ref{qc}, cont'd)
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I'm trying to create an environment which has this behavior but I'm not seeing a solution.

I've also thought that perhaps I could change the **first** item (such that it does not get a `\newpage` before the item is defined), as it might be easier to check if the counter is zero.

Also, as a bonus, is it possible to create two different types of `\item`s depending on the behavior expected (for example, if for a question I didn't want to add any extra pages)?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach that allows for more manipulations, if needed.

I split the entire environment's contents at `\question`, remove the first item in the sequence because it will be blank, and then deliver the sequence adding `\newpage\item` between items.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{environ,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{questions}
 {
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l_malu_questions_seq { \question } \BODY
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_malu_questions_seq \l_tmpa_tl % remove the initial blank
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item \seq_use:Nn \l_malu_questions_seq { \newpage\item }
  \end{enumerate}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn { NnV }
\seq_new:N \l_malu_questions_seq
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Questions:

\begin{questions}
  \question \label{qa} This is a question.
    \newpage
    (Question \ref{qa}, cont'd)
  \question \label{qb} Another question.
    \newpage
    (Question \ref{qb}, cont'd)
  \question \label{qc} Final question.  Note that there is only one "newpage" after it.
    \newpage
    (Question \ref{qc}, cont'd)
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the usage of a few Boolean flags and checks we could achieve what you asked for:

1. After each question, add a new blank page with some text at the top (such as *(question X, cont'd)*.
2. Then start the next question on a new page.
3. Create two different types of `\item`s depending on the behavior expected, for example, for a question we don't want to add any extra page.

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
% First, optional argument, put [n] for no extra page needed
% Second, question text
\NewDocumentCommand\qitem{O{}m}{\iftoggle{qstarted}%
  % Already a non first question, needs a newpage 
  {\newpage}
  % First question, set flag, does not need a newpage
  {\toggletrue{qstarted}}
\item\label{ql\arabic{enumi}}#2
  % Check if the user wanted an extra page for this question
  \ifstrequal{#1}{n}
  % Did not want an extra page
  {\relax}
  % Wanted an extra page
  {\newpage 
    (Question \ref{ql\arabic{enumi}}, cont'd)}}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newtoggle{qstarted}
\togglefalse{qstarted}

\begin{document}

Questions:

\begin{enumerate}
  \qitem{This is a question.}

  \qitem{Another question.}

  \qitem[n]{This question will not have an extra page}

  \qitem{Final question.  Note that there is only one "newpage" after
    it.}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

---

**The Output**

The code achieves exactly what you asked for.

[image]

---

**How It Works?**

Flag `qstarted` keeps track of whether we are past the first question. This
flag is set to false as soon as we start the first question.

We added an optional argument `[n]` to `\qitem`. If this
argument if found to be set, no  extra page
is generated.

Answer (score 1):

You can automate the process of adding a `\newpage` before every `\item` but delay the *first* `\newpage` use [a cunning trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89187/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{questions}
  {\let\olditem\item
   % Delay \newpage by one \question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89187/5764)
   \def\itemnewpage{\def\itemnewpage{\newpage}}%
   \def\question{\itemnewpage\olditem}%
   \begin{enumerate}
     \let\item\question}
  {\end{enumerate}}

\begin{document}

Questions:

\begin{questions}
  \question \label{qa} This is a question.
    \newpage
    (Question \ref{qa}, cont'd)

  \question \label{qb} Another question.
    \newpage
    (Question \ref{qb}, cont'd)

  \question \label{qc} Final question.
    \newpage
    (Question \ref{qc}, cont'd)
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

I defined some semantic language for your environment and questions. This way it makes sense what they mean.

If the structure of your `\question`s are always the same (question, followed by a blank page, then the wording `Question X (cont'd)` and a blank page), one can automate that process as well.

Comment: What's the purpose of `\let\olditem\item`, as you're using `\question` in the environment?