# Macro to apply a custom command to a conditional datatool definition

Tags: tables, macros, indexing, datatool, comma-separated-list

This is somewhat of an expansion of the previous question:[Macro to apply a custom command across a comma-separated list](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/409805/macro-to-apply-a-custom-command-across-a-comma-separated-list)

I'm working on creating a garden journal in LaTex. I have a .csv database file of plants ([db-1.csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/190Ff5kKRhWpp9rTWUGoCk07p3QknJzvJ/view?usp=sharing)) from which I create subset tables for each area of my garden using conditions from the datatool package, which has been working great.

I would like to index the plants that are pulled from the database in each of my tables. I am currently using the makeidx package. This way, my final index will include where a particular plant was mentioned even if the mention occurred in a table and not in the text directly.

How can I make my apply macro work on the results of my datatool conditions (\theback)?

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book} 
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{colortbl}
%necessary to color a table

\definecolor{lightmauve}{rgb}{0.86, 0.82, 1.0}

\usepackage{makeidx} % Required to make an index
\makeindex % Tells LaTeX to create the files required for indexing



% This command is for applying a single command to a comma-separated list of tokens, and listing the results separated by ", " (I removed the ``,'').
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\apply}[3][]{
% #1: optional separator to print between applications; default=[, ]
% #2: command to apply; 
% #3: list to apply command to 
  \def\itemsep{\def\itemsep{#1}} % first call to \itemsep prints nothing; later calls print #1
  \def\zz{\itemsep#2}%
  \@for \listelement:=#3\do{\expandafter\zz\expandafter{\listelement}}%
}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\DTLloaddb{dbsample}{db-1.csv}


\begin{document}

%First I'm creating my custom comma-separated list, the result of datatool conditions.  Can be called using \theback

\def\theback{\DTLforeach*[\DTLisSubString{\Location}{back}]{dbsample}%
{\Name=Name,\Variety=Variety,\Location=Location,\Established=Established}%
{\Name!\Variety, }}

\vspace{10mm}

%%% Now ideally I'd like to have 
%\apply{\index}{\theback} 
%to work in my table, but it does not.  This did not work, I may have to figure out how to set a macro (or definition?) within a macro???


%Next, this is my table.

\begin{table}[htbp] 
\caption{Plants that are pre-existing are highlighted in \colorbox{lightmauve}{lightmauve}} 
\vspace{5mm}
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{lllr} 
\bfseries Name & 
\bfseries Variety&
\bfseries Location & 
\bfseries Established % 
\DTLforeach*[\DTLisSubString{\Location}{back}]{dbsample}%
{\Name=Name,\Variety=Variety,\Location=Location,\Established=Established}
{% 
\DTLifSubString{\Established}{yes}{\\\rowcolor{lightmauve}}{\\\rowcolor{white}}%
\Name & \Variety & \Location & \Established}
\end{tabular} 

\apply{\index}{Daffodil!apricot,St. John's Wort}
%the above will work, but what I'm hoping for is instead, something along the lines of:
%\apply{\index}{\theback}

\end{table}


\printindex % Output the index

\end{document}
```

Sorry, I'm not sure if I'm referring to things with the correct names.  Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you so much!

Comment: So my comment now is obsolete, thus let's delete obsolete comments. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the answer to the question [How to change the space between the itemize “items” in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/12374), `\itemsep` is already defined in LaTeX.

If you wish, you can combine the exchanging of non-delimited macro-arguments with good old `\romannumeral`-expansion for defining a macro which checks the toplevel-expansion of `\Variety` for emptiness and then appends the things needed for an index-entry to a comma-list-macro (called `\theback`)—I tried to explain `\romannumeral`-expansion in my answer to the question [How can I know the number of expandafters when appending to a csname macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339782/118714).

In the example below I decided to go the `\xdef...{\unexpanded{...}}`-route in order to have `\unexpanded` work against LaTeX's halving of the amount of consecutive hashes with each macro-expansion. Take this for a moot point. ;-)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book} 
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{colortbl}
%necessary to color a table

\definecolor{lightmauve}{rgb}{0.86, 0.82, 1.0}

\usepackage{makeidx} % Required to make an index
\makeindex % Tells LaTeX to create the files required for indexing

\makeatletter

%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                  {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                    which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                  {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                    which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\@firstoftwo\expandafter{} \@secondoftwo}%
  {\@firstoftwo\expandafter{} \@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Exchange two arguments:
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\exchangeargs[2]{#2#1}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Append comma-delimited element to comma-list-macro holding index-entries:
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\GlobalAppendIndexEntryToCommalist[5]{%
  % #1 = comma-list-macro where tokens/index-entries are to be appended
  % #2 = !
  % #3 = ,
  % #4 = \Name
  % #5 = \Variety
  \xdef#1{%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{%
      \romannumeral0%
      \expandafter\exchangeargs\expandafter{\expandafter{%
        \romannumeral0%
        \expandafter\CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{#5}{%
          \expandafter\exchangeargs\expandafter{#4}{ }%
        }{%
          \expandafter\exchangeargs\expandafter{#5}{%
            \exchangeargs{#2}{%
              \expandafter\exchangeargs\expandafter{#4}{ }%
            }%
          }%
        }%
      }}{%
        \expandafter\CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{#1}{ }{%
          \expandafter\exchangeargs\expandafter{#1#3}{ }%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%

\newcommand*\theback{}%
\newcommand*\GlobalResettheback{\gdef\theback{}}%

% This macro applies a command to each element of a list of comma-separated arguments:
\newcommand{\apply}[2]{%
  % #1: command to apply; 
  % #2: (macro holding) list of comma-separated arguments;
  \@for\listelement:=#2\do{%
    \expandafter\exchangeargs\expandafter{\expandafter{\listelement}}{#1}%
  }%
}%

\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\DTLloaddb{dbsample}{db-1.csv}

\begin{document}

%This is my table.

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Plants that are pre-existing are highlighted in \colorbox{lightmauve}{lightmauve}}
\vspace{5mm}%
\centering 
\GlobalResettheback
\begin{tabular}{lllr} 
\bfseries Name & 
\bfseries Variety&
\bfseries Location & 
\bfseries Established %
\DTLforeach*[\DTLisSubString{\Location}{back}]{dbsample}%
{\Name=Name,\Variety=Variety,\Location=Location,\Established=Established}
{%
  \DTLifSubString{\Established}{yes}{\\\rowcolor{lightmauve}}{\\\rowcolor{white}}%
  \Name & \Variety & \Location & \Established%
  \GlobalAppendIndexEntryToCommalist{\theback}{!}{,}{\Name}{\Variety}%
}%
\end{tabular} 
%
%\apply{\index}{Daffodil!apricot,St. John's Wort}
%\show\theback
\apply{\index}{\theback}
%
% !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
% Be aware: 
%
% If you decide to have tables not as floating objects but as part of the 
% main text and switch to tabularx for having multipage-tables, then 
% carrying out all \index-commands _after_ already having shipped all pages
% of the table may yield wrong page-numbers with index-entries of things
% that do not occur on the last page of the table but do occur on pages
% prior to that last page.
%
% That's why below I added a suggestion where index-entries are produced
% and \index-commands are carried out at the time of producing the
% table-rows via \DTLforeach*.
% !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
%
\end{table}

\printindex % Output the index

\end{document}
```

Probably you don't need to maintain such a comma-list-macro but can have LaTeX construct the index-entry from within the `\DTLforeach*`-loop directly:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book} 
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{colortbl}
%necessary to color a table

\definecolor{lightmauve}{rgb}{0.86, 0.82, 1.0}

\usepackage{makeidx} % Required to make an index
\makeindex % Tells LaTeX to create the files required for indexing

\makeatletter
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                  {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                    which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                  {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                    which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\@firstoftwo\expandafter{} \@secondoftwo}%
  {\@firstoftwo\expandafter{} \@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Exchange two arguments:
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\exchangeargs[2]{#2#1}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Construct index-entry from \Name and \Variety
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\ConstructIndexentry[4]{%
  % #1 = indexing-command, usually \index
  % #2 = !
  % #3 = \Name
  % #4 = \Variety
  \expandafter\exchangeargs\expandafter{\expandafter{%
    \romannumeral0%
    \expandafter\CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{#4}{%
      \expandafter\exchangeargs\expandafter{#3}{ }%
    }{%
      \expandafter\exchangeargs\expandafter{#4}{%
        \exchangeargs{#2}{%
          \expandafter\exchangeargs\expandafter{#3}{ }%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }}{#1}%
}%
\makeatother

\DTLloaddb{dbsample}{db-1.csv}

\begin{document}

%This is the table.

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Plants that are pre-existing are highlighted in \colorbox{lightmauve}{lightmauve}}
\vspace{5mm}%
\centering 
\begin{tabular}{lllr} 
\bfseries Name & 
\bfseries Variety&
\bfseries Location & 
\bfseries Established %
\DTLforeach*[\DTLisSubString{\Location}{back}]{dbsample}%
{\Name=Name,\Variety=Variety,\Location=Location,\Established=Established}
{%
  \DTLifSubString{\Established}{yes}{\\\rowcolor{lightmauve}}{\\\rowcolor{white}}%
  \Name & \Variety & \Location & \Established%
  \ConstructIndexentry{\index}{!}{\Name}{\Variety}%
}%
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\printindex % Output the index

\end{document}
```