# Loop over an optional argument

Tags: macros, counters, loops

I'd like to use the command `\foo` with an optional argument to step and print the counter value iterated according to the number passed.

So, for example, `\foo[5]` should step the counter 5 times, one by one.

**(!)** Note that it is not the same as `\stepcounter{}{5}`.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{report}

\newcounter{mycount}
\setcounter{mycount}{0}
\newcommand{\foo}{\stepcounter{mycount}counter is \textbf{\themycount}}

\begin{document}
first use: \foo

second use: \foo

now using with option to iterate: \foo[2]

\medskip

\textit{desired output from line above should be:}

\medskip

now using with option to iterate: counter is \textbf{3,4}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

With `expl3` it's just a few lines.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{mycount}
\setcounter{mycount}{0}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{O{1}}
 {
  \int_compare:nT { #1 > 0 }
   {
    \int_compare:nTF { #1 = 1 } {counter~is} {counters~are}~
    \stepcounter{mycount}
    \textbf{\themycount}
    \prg_replicate:nn { #1 - 1 } {,\stepcounter{mycount}\textbf{\themycount}}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
first use: \foo

second use: \foo

now using with option to iterate: \foo[2]

now using with option to iterate: counters are \textbf{3,4}

\foo[5]

\end{document}
```

The trick is to do the first iteration and then proceed again adding first a comma.

If the number passed is zero or less nothing happens.

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I need.

Comment: Do you think is it possible to change the text also if there is argument? I mean, to print `counters are 5,6,7,8` for example.

Comment: @Sigur Your wish is my command. Updated.

Comment: Oh, I think I should learn about `\NewDocumentCommand` as soon as possible. Amazing and powerful.

Answer (score 4):

Here is short code with `multido`, `xparse` and `etoolbox`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{xparse, etoolbox}
\newcounter{mycount}
\setcounter{mycount}{0}
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{O{1}}{counter is \multido{\i=1+1}{#1}{\stepcounter{mycount}\textbf{\themycount}\ifnumless{\multidocount}{#1}{,\,}{.}}}

\begin{document}

first use: \foo

second use: \foo

now using with option to iterate: \foo[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach using [`multido`](//ctan.org/pkg/multido) for looping and a [delayed delimiter definition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89187/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multido}

\newcounter{mycount}

\newcommand{\foo}[1][1]{%
  counter%
  \ifnum#1>1\relax s are\else \space is\fi
  \space
  % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89187/5764
  \def\itemdelim{\unskip\space\def\itemdelim{,\space}}% Item delimiter delayed by one cycle
  {\bfseries\multido{\i=1+1}{#1}{\itemdelim \stepcounter{mycount}\themycount}}%
}

\begin{document}

first use: \foo

second use: \foo

now using with option to iterate: \foo[2]

\medskip

\textit{desired output from line above should be:}

\medskip

now using with option to iterate: counters are \textbf{3, 4}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This solution is more understandable to me... but  I had never done it by myself. Very nice.

Answer (score 3):

With `pgffor` it is even less lines.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcounter{mycount}
\setcounter{mycount}{0}
\newcommand{\foo}[1][1]{counter is \foreach \X [count=\Y] in
{1,...,#1}{\stepcounter{mycount}%
\textbf{\themycount}\ifnum\Y=#1%
\else%
,\fi}}

\begin{document}
first use: \foo

second use: \foo

now using with option to iterate: \foo[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A bit more code but without additional packages:

```
\documentclass{report}

\newcounter{mycount}
\setcounter{mycount}{0}

\newcommand\Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand{\foo}[1][1]{\fooloop{#1}{}{counter value is}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\fooloop}[3]{%
  \ifnum#1>0 \stepcounter{mycount}\fi
  \ifnum#1>1 \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
  {% 
    \begingroup
    \protected@edef\@tempa{\themycount}%
    \c@mycount=#1\relax
    \advance\c@mycount by -1\relax
    \expandafter\endgroup
    \expandafter\fooloop\expandafter
    {\number\expandafter\c@mycount\expandafter}\expandafter
    {\romannumeral0\expandafter\Exchange\expandafter{\@tempa}{ #2}, }%
    {counter values are}%
  }{%
    #3 \textbf{#2\themycount}%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
first use: \foo

second use: \foo

now using with option to iterate: \foo[4]

\medskip

\textit{desired output from line above should be:}

\medskip

now using with option to iterate: counter values are \textbf{3, 4, 5, 6}

\medskip

now using with option to iterate 0 times---counter is unchanged and displayed: \foo[0]

\medskip

now using with option to iterate -1 times---counter is unchanged and displayed: \foo[-1]

\end{document}
```

[image]