# Spacing setting of math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing

In typing of an article, I need to type many formulas like

```
$ \left( a, b,c,d | e,f,g,h \right) $.
```

Since they are too tight, I should add space using `\,` command to obtain

```
$ \left( a, \, b, \, c, \, d | e, \, f, \, g, \, h \right) $.
```

But my problem is there are too many of such formulas. Is there any command which changes the default spacing between characters in the math mode?

Comment: `\[\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c&d&e&f&g&h\end{pmatrix}\]` (don't forget to add `\usepackage{amsmath}` to the preamble) could be an option.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you don't need the thing in subscripts or superscripts, the easiest way is to exit from math mode, doubling the `\thinmuskip`, reentering math mode, typesetting the lists and go back.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\cls}[2]{%
  \mathord{\mbox{%
    \thinmuskip=2\thinmuskip
    $(#1\mid#2)$%
  }}%
}

\begin{document}

$( a, b,c,d \mid e,f,g,h)$

$(a,\, b,\, c,\, d \mid e,\, f,\, g,\, h)$

$\cls{a,b,c,d}{e,f,g,h}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different solution that allows for resizing the parentheses as usual for commands defined with `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`, see the examples. It also has a friendlier syntax.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\AtBeginDocument{\mathchardef\clscomma=\mathcode`, }

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\cls}{som}
 {
  \group_begin:
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \hs_cls_auto:n { #3 }
   }
   {
    \hs_cls_manual:nn { #2 } { #3 }
   }
  \group_end:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \hs_cls_auto:n
 {
  \__hs_cls_activate_comma:
  \__hs_cls_activate_bar:n { \;\middle\vert\; }
  \left( #1 \right)
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \hs_cls_manual:nn
 {
  \__hs_cls_activate_comma:
  \__hs_cls_activate_bar:n { \__hs_cls_mid:n {#1} }
  \__hs_cls_open:n {#1} #2 \__hs_cls_close:n {#1}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__hs_cls_activate_comma:
 {
  \char_set_active_eq:nN { `, } \__hs_cls_comma:
  \mathcode`,="8000 \scan_stop:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__hs_cls_comma: { \clscomma\, }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__hs_cls_activate_bar:n
 {
  \cs_set_protected:Nn \__hs_cls_bar: { #1 }
  \char_set_active_eq:nN { `| } \__hs_cls_bar:
  \mathcode`|="8000 \scan_stop:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__hs_cls_open:n
 {
  \tl_if_novalue:nTF { #1 } { ( } { \mathopen{#1(} }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__hs_cls_mid:n
 {
  \tl_if_novalue:nTF { #1 } { \mid } { \mathrel{#1\vert} }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__hs_cls_close:n
 {
  \tl_if_novalue:nTF { #1 } { ) } { \mathclose{#1)} }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$( a, b,c,d \mid e,f,g,h)$

$(a,\, b,\, c,\, d \mid e,\, f,\, g,\, h)$

$\cls{a,b,c,d|e,f,g,h}$

$\cls[\Big]{a,b,c,d|e,f,g,h}$

$\cls*{\dfrac{a}{2},b,c,d|e,f,g,h}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comments and answers but I need a more general command of  `\thinmuskip=2\thinmuskip`

Comment: @HS8637 Why? A comma is followed by a thin space and `\,` inserts another thin space; the thin space has width `\thinmuskip`, so you get *exactly* the same output with my code and with `,\,` all around.

Comment: Dear @egreg. You're right. But I need to change the setting of spacing, not an especial case.

Comment: @HS8637 Reread your question. Those are the formulas you mention. Changing in general the spacing after commas is not something I'd recommend.

Comment: @egreg Thanks for adding the LaTeX3 code, it is full of little interesting things!

Answer (score 9):

You can process each of the two lists (left and right) using [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) and a [cunning delimiter trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89187/5764):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89187/5764
\newcommand{\printlist}[2][,]{%
  \def\itemdelim{\def\itemdelim{#1}}% Item delimiter delayed by one cycle
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\itemdelim##1}% How each item is processed
  \docsvlist{#2}}% Process CSV list

\makeatletter
\def\@LandR#1|#2\relax{\def\leftlist{#1}\def\rightlist{#2}}%
\def\LandR#1{%
  \@LandR#1\relax
  \left( % Left bracket
  \edef\x{\noexpand\printlist[,\,]{\leftlist}}\x
  \,\middle|\, % Middle divider
  \edef\x{\noexpand\printlist[,\,]{\rightlist}}\x
  \right) % Right bracket
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\left( a, b, c, d | e, f, g, h \right)$

$\LandR{a, b, c, d | e, f, g, h}$

\end{document}
```

Each list is printed using `\printlist[,\,]`, which adds a small space `\,` after each delimiter `,`. You can adjust the layout of the left/right bracket and middle divider.

If you wish to include larger constructions, you may need to use `\noexpand`, as in

```
\LandR{\noexpand\frac{a}{b}, c, d, e | f, g, h, \noexpand\frac{i}{j}}
```