# How is \char processed in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, tex-core

The following example produces

[image]

```
${\rm\char"5}$
\end
```

Why does it not produce the following instead?

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The TeXbook p. 289 explains how `\char〈8-bit number〉` can form a 〈character〉, and that a 〈character〉 is a particular case of a 〈math symbol〉. What a 〈math symbol〉 found in math mode does is explained on page 291, but let's get back to page 289 about 〈character〉:

> When TeX is in math mode or display math mode, a 〈character〉
>   command takes on added significance: It specifies a number between 0 and 32767 = 2<sup>15</sup> − 1. This is done by replacing the character number by its `\mathcode` value. If the `\mathcode` value turns out to be `32768` = `"8000` however, the 〈character〉 is replaced by an active character token having the original character code (0 to 255); TeX forgets the original 〈character〉 and expands this active character according to the rules of Chapter 20.

So, what matters when finding `\char〈8-bit number〉` in math mode is the `\mathcode` of the specified character. In your case, the character is number 5, i.e. `` `\^^E ``. Line 59 of plain.tex reads:

```latex
\mathcode`\^^E="023A % \lnot
```

Therefore `\char"5` in math mode is a 〈math symbol〉 with `\mathcode` `"023A`. It specifies class 0 (ordinary, cf. TeXbook p. 154), family 2 and position `"3A` in the corresponding font.

The font in question is thus `\textfont2`, because your `\rm` does nothing here, AFAICT:

```latex
\rm:
macro:->\fam \z@ \tenrm
```

`\fam` has an effect on symbols of class 7 (variable), but here the symbol has class 0; besides, `\tenrm` affects the text font and has no effect in math mode, AFAIK (except of course if you temporarily leave math mode using, for instance, an `\hbox` command inside the dollar signs).

You may query what this font is with:

```latex
\tracingonline=1
\showthe\textfont2
```

which outputs:

```
> \tensy .
l.3 \showthe\textfont2
```

and confirms what can be seen with `\tracingoutput=1`:

```latex
Completed box being shipped out [1]
\vbox(667.20255+0.0)x469.75499

(...)

.\vbox(643.20255+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 633.20255fill
..\glue(\topskip) 5.69446
..\hbox(4.30554+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 443.0883fil
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x20.0
...\mathon
...\tensy :
...\mathoff

(...)
```

`:` indeed has ASCII code `"3A`. So, the character you get in the output is found in position `"3A` of font `\tensy`. The TeXbook p. 350 (plain.tex) declares:

```latex
\font\tensy=cmsy10
```

You can verify with `texdoc encguide` (page 33 here) that character `"3A` of font `cmsy10` is indeed the `\lnot` we see on your screenshot.

Note: this is not directly related to the question, but since its crux is the `\mathcode` and the paragraph I quoted from the TeXbook explains what happens with the special case of a `\mathcode` equal to `"8000`, I'll seize the opportunity and point our dear readers to this [answer of egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/501452/73317) where the `"8000` special case is put to good use (cf. function `\__hs_cls_activate_comma:` in his answer).

Comment: Behavior of `\char` is also described on top of p.155 in TeXbook.

Comment: an interesting case arises when mathcode for a `<character>` has not been defined - then mathcode is taken to be equal to charcode

Comment: Incidentally, is it possible to "undefine" a mathcode if it has already been defined? For example, how to change `$\mathcode"5=0 \char"5$` so that `П` would be printed, instead of `Г`.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to undefine a `\mathcode`, and the top of page 155 says that INITEX starts in a state where the `\mathcode` for *every* possible character code (256 values in Knuth's TeX) is defined. And beware, one doesn't have `\mathcode` *x* = *x* for digits and letters in this case: it's *x* +`"7000` for the 10 digits and *x* +`"7100` for the 52 letters. This makes in-math digits in roman type by default, and in-math letters in italic type by default (and can be overriden with `\fam`). To get your `П`, simply point to position 5 of `\textfont0` which is by default `cmr10`.

Comment: You can do that with: `\mathcode"5="0005 $\char"5$ \end`. You could set up many `\mathcode` entries like that in a file you `\input` or in a custom format. Note that this treats the character as a mathematical entity (a 〈math symbol〉). If it's really text inside  a formula, `$\hbox{\char"5}$` seems more appropriate and needs no particular font or `\mathcode` setup (of course, `\char"5` also works in horizontal mode without needing dollar signs nor `\hbox`: it causes a character box to be appended to the horizontal list).