# Global Definition of a List

Tags: macros, lists, enumerate

I found some sort of a list online and got it to work as intended
The command "addtoaliste" is adding a parameter to the list "aliste".
It's defined by newcommands, so I have problems getting it to work within environments such as enumerate, as any changes are only done locally.

I'll try to change my implemented list to be working with global definitions (gdef). But first my "command-code":

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newcommand{\aliste}[1]{\empty}
\def\zaliste#1\relax{\def\aliste##1{#1}}
\newcommand{\addtoaliste}[1]{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\aliste{}}{}}{
    \expandafter\zaliste\aliste{##1}#1\relax}
    {\expandafter\zaliste\aliste{##1},#1\relax}
}

\begin{document}
    Value: \aliste{}\\ %Returns empty list
    \addtoaliste{1}
    Value: \aliste{} %Returns 1
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item First Point. 
        \addtoaliste{2}
    \end{enumerate}
    Value: \aliste{} %shall return 1,2, but still returns 1
\end{document}
```

I tried some changes and got to the following, but it still didn't work as intended:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\gdef\aliste#1{}
\gdef\zaliste#1{\relax{\gdef\aliste##1{#1}}}
\gdef\addtoaliste#1{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\aliste{}}{}}{
    \expandafter\zaliste\aliste{##1}#1\relax}
    {\expandafter\zaliste\aliste{##1},#1\relax}
}

\begin{document}
Value: \aliste{}\\ %Returns empty list
\addtoaliste{1}
Value: \aliste{}\\ %Returns 1
\begin{enumerate}
    \item First Point. 
    \addtoaliste{2}
\end{enumerate}
Value: \aliste{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Take your first code and replace one `\def` by a `\gdef`: `\def\zaliste#1\relax{\gdef\aliste##1{#1}}`.

Comment: Great thanks seems to work right now. Any thoughts or suggestions why it's not working with both or even more gdef?

Comment: It has not directly to do with the `\gdef`s but with the fact that the first code has `\newcommand{\aliste}[1]{\empty}`, which is not the same as `\def\aliste#1{}`, and thus the "globalization" to `\gdef\aliste#1{}" does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `\gdef` does not really change the code: `\gdef` means “globally define”, but it's the code inside the macro that should do a global definition. So

```
\def\zaliste#1\relax{\gdef\aliste##1{#1}}
```

would be the solution, provided the macros work to begin with, which they don't.

The problem is in

```latex
\def\zaliste#1{\relax{\gdef\aliste##1{#1}}}
```

where an extra pair of braces ruins everything: it should be

```latex
\def\zaliste#1\relax{\gdef\aliste##1{#1}}
```

so the argument is delimited by `\relax`. Indeed

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\def\aliste#1{}
\def\zaliste#1\relax{\gdef\aliste##1{#1}}
\def\addtoaliste#1{%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\aliste{}}{}}{%
    \expandafter\zaliste\aliste{##1}#1\relax}%
    {\expandafter\zaliste\aliste{##1},#1\relax}%
}

\begin{document}

Value: \aliste{} %Returns empty list

\addtoaliste{1}
Value: \aliste{} %Returns 1

\begin{enumerate}
    \item First Point.
    \addtoaliste{2}
\end{enumerate}
Value: \aliste{}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

I'm not sure why you define `\aliste` with an argument, which just complicates things. In the following, I also changed `\gdef` to `\xdef` so as to expand the value, in case you want to use something like `\addtoalist{\arabic{enumi}}`

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\def\aliste{}
\def\zaliste#1\relax{\xdef\aliste{#1}} % \xdef for full expansion
\def\addtoaliste#1{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\aliste}{}}{%
    \expandafter\zaliste\aliste#1\relax
  }{\expandafter\zaliste\aliste,#1\relax
  }%
}

\begin{document}

Value: \aliste %Returns empty list

\addtoaliste{1}
Value: \aliste %Returns 1

\begin{enumerate}
    \item First Point.
    \addtoaliste{2}
\end{enumerate}
Value: \aliste

\end{document}
```

will produce exactly the same.

I propose a different approach that supports as many lists as you want.

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\startlist}{m}
 {
  \clist_clear_new:c { g_wuagh_list_#1_clist }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtolist}{mm}
 {
  % add the item
  \clist_gput_right:cx { g_wuagh_list_#1_clist } { #2 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\uselist}{om}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF { #1 }
   {
    \clist_use:cn { g_wuagh_list_#2_clist } { , }
   }
   {
    \clist_item:cn { g_wuagh_list_#2_clist } { #1 }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\startlist{a}

\begin{document}

Value: \uselist{a} %Returns empty list

\addtolist{a}{A}
Value: \uselist{a} %Returns 1

\begin{enumerate}
    \item First Point.\addtolist{a}{\arabic{enumi}}
    \item Second Point.\addtolist{a}{\arabic{enumi}}
\end{enumerate}
Value: \uselist{a}

Item: \uselist[1]{a} % returns A

Item: \uselist[2]{a} % returns 1


\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, you can also access list items by their index.

Comment: Great clarifications, will look into your own list-thingy, as it's more flexible.

Comment: @WuaghhhhXMA It would be possible to abstract also your code in order to support more lists, but as `expl3` already provides the infrastructure, I see no need to.

Comment: Just one additional question: When adding the enumi-counter from the environment to the list, it's always adding the last counter (no matter when added). Any quick tip?

Comment: @WuaghhhhXMA Just change to `\xdef` instead of `\gdef`. I changed the `expl3` version to show how to do it in the more flexible setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to manage the list for you (addition and processing/printing):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89187/5764
% \printlist[<separator>]{<list>}
\newcommand{\printlist}[2][,]{%
  \def\itemdelim{\def\itemdelim{#1}}% Item delimiter delayed by one cycle
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\itemdelim##1}% How each item is processed
  \dolistcsloop{#2}}% Process CSV list
\newcommand{\addtoaliste}{\listcsgadd{aliste}}

\begin{document}

Value: \printlist{aliste} % Returns empty list

\addtoaliste{1}

Value: \printlist{aliste} % Returns 1
\begin{enumerate}
  \item First Point. 
  \addtoaliste{2}
\end{enumerate}
Value: \printlist{aliste} % Returns 1,2

\end{document}
```

The list printing uses a [cunning (La)TeX trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89187/5764).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this package.