# LaTeX etoolbox list not working in environment

Tags: xetex, pdftex, etoolbox

I'm working on LaTeX and I want to add an element to a list each time I call an environment (here the `environment` environment).

When I run the document the result is 
`['command']` instead of `['environment','command']` that I would like to have.

When I put the command to add the element to the list (`\listadd{\languagelist}{environment}`) in the `\newenvironment` definition and call it one the document, it doesn't works (`environment` is missing in the list).

Do you please have any solution ?

Thanks for your help,

Cordially,

Thomas

*Here's the code :*

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%COMMAND FOUND ON INTERNET AND WORKS
% \printlist[<sep>]{<list macro>}
\newcommand{\printlist}[2][,]{{% Print list
  % http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89187/5764
  \def\listsep{\def\listsep{#1}}% Delayed execution of list separator
  \renewcommand{\do}[1]{\listsep`##1'}%
  [\dolistloop\languagelist]
}}

%Create the environment that is supposed to add environment to the list every time I call it
\newenvironment{environment}{
\listadd{\languagelist}{environment}}{}

%Create the command that add command to the list every time I call it
\newcommand{\command}{
\listadd{\languagelist}{command}}


\begin{document}

%Add environment to the list
\begin{environment}
\end{environment}

%Add command to the list
\command

%Expected result : ['environment','command']
%Result : ['command']
\printlist{\languagelist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `\listgadd` instead of `\listadd`.

Comment: Thanks you very much, it works !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environments form groups, so your `\listadd` won't survive the end of the group.

You can use `\listgadd`, instead, that does a “global addition”.

However, I suggest a more robust solution with `expl3`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% \printlist[<sep>]{<list name>}
\NewDocumentCommand{\printlist}{ O{,}mo }
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}
   {% no trailing optional argument, use the default wrapper: #1 -> `#1'
    \cs_set_eq:NN \__thomas_list_wrap:n \__thomas_list_wrap_default:n
   }
   {% locally define the template
    \cs_set:Nn \__thomas_list_wrap:n { #3 }
   }
  \thomas_list_print:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

% \addtolist{<list name>}{<item>}
\NewDocumentCommand{\addtolist}{mm}
 {
  \thomas_list_add:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

% variables
\seq_new:N \l__thomas_list_tmp_seq

% internal functions
\cs_new:Nn \__thomas_list_wrap_default:n { `#1' }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \thomas_list_print:nn
 {
  \seq_clear:N \l__thomas_list_tmp_seq
  \seq_map_inline:cn { g__thomas_list_#2_seq }
   {
    \seq_put_right:Nn \l__thomas_list_tmp_seq { \__thomas_list_wrap:n { ##1 } }
   }
  [\seq_use:Nn \l__thomas_list_tmp_seq { #1 }]
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \thomas_list_add:nn
 {
  \seq_if_exist:cF { g__thomas_list_#1_seq }
   {
    \seq_new:c { g__thomas_list_#1_seq }
   }
  \seq_gput_right:cn { g__thomas_list_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

%Create the environment that is supposed to add environment to the list every time I call it
\newenvironment{environment}
 {\addtolist{languagelist}{environment}}
 {}

%Create the command that add command to the list every time I call it
\newcommand{\command}{%
  \addtolist{languagelist}{command}%
}


\begin{document}

%Add environment to the list
\begin{environment}
\end{environment}

%Add command to the list
\command

%Expected result : ['environment','command']
%Result : ['command']
\printlist{languagelist}

\printlist[;]{languagelist}

\printlist[;]{languagelist}[``#1'']

\end{document}
```

The trailing argument to `\printlist` is a template for wrapping each item with some function.

[image]