# LaTeX, etoolbox and counters

Tags: xetex, etoolbox

I'm having a new issue with the `etoolbox` package.

In fact, I would like in a LaTeX document to numberize my figures, tables, etc...

But, when I add the value of the counter to the list, it doesn't add the current value (that is increasing) but it's adding the final value. As if `etoolbox` is executing the commands at the end of the document.

Do you please have any solution ?

Cordially,

Thomas Fauchet

PS : Using `expl3` doesn't solve the problem.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%COMMAND FOUND ON INTERNET AND WORKS
% \printlist[<sep>]{<list macro>}
\newcommand{\printlist}[2][,]{{% Print list
  % http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89187/5764
  \def\listsep{\def\listsep{#1}}% Delayed execution of list separator
  \renewcommand{\do}[1]{\listsep`##1'}%
  [\dolistloop\languagelist]
}}


\newcounter{test}
\stepcounter{test}

\begin{document}

%Add 1
\listgadd{\languagelist}{\thetest}
\stepcounter{test}
%Add 2
\listgadd{\languagelist}{\thetest}

%Expected result : ['1','2']
%Result : ['2','2']
\printlist{\languagelist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of asking a new question for every attempt, wouldn't it be easier to ask the *real* question with all the details?

Comment: OK, but my problem is so fat that I didn't want to take your time...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `\listxadd` to expand the value:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%COMMAND FOUND ON INTERNET AND WORKS
% \printlist[<sep>]{<list macro>}
\newcommand{\printlist}[2][,]{{% Print list
  % http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89187/5764
  \def\listsep{\def\listsep{#1}}% Delayed execution of list separator
  \renewcommand{\do}[1]{\listsep`##1'}%
  [\dolistloop\languagelist]
}}


\newcounter{test}
\stepcounter{test}

\begin{document}

%Add 1
\listxadd{\languagelist}{\thetest}
\stepcounter{test}
%Add 2
\listxadd{\languagelist}{\thetest}

%Expected result : ['1','2']
%Result : ['2','2']
\printlist{\languagelist}

\end{document}
```