# Horizontal List of items with separator as an item under another item

Tags: lists

I want to write a section of Skills in resume where the output will be like-

**Personal Attributes**

Independent | Curious | Adaptable | Problem Solver

**Technical Skills**

Java | Python | AWS

the above outtput I want to achieve with something like

```
\begin{skills}

\skilltype{Personla Attributes}
    \begin{skilllist}
    
    \item{Independent}
    \item{curious}
    \item{adaptable}

    \end{skilllist}
.
.
.
.
\begin{skills}
```

How sould I write the .cls file to have \textpipes in between?
P.s. I don't want to write it like `Curious \textpipe Adaptable` etc.

### additionally

would be great if possible a solution where the items are equally distributed and spacing between them is auto generated accordingly

Comment: Define "equally distributed". Would 3 items (say) take up the same space as 5 items? Or should it just be spread across `\textwidth`?

Comment: @Werner i mean irrespictive of 3 items or 5 items, they should occupy whole line (not equal width per items, but spacing should auto adjust)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an `inline` list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\newlist{skillset}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[skillset]{label={}, afterlabel={}, itemjoin={{ \textbar{} }}}

\begin{document}
\begin{skillset}
  \item Java
  \item Python
  \item AWS
\end{skillset}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To make the list take the whole line add `\hfill` to the `itemjoin`. Margins shown:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} % to show margins
\newlist{skillset}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[skillset]{label={}, afterlabel={}, itemjoin={{\hfill \textbar{} \hfill}}}
\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{skillset}
  \item Java
  \item Python
  \item AWS
\end{skillset}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can directly define a new list with `\newlist{skilllist}{enumerate*}{1}` and then say `setlist[skilllist]{label={}, afterlabel={}, itemjoin={{ \textbar{} }}}`

Comment: @JasperHabicht Good point. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Then I'll remove mine =)

Comment: @JasperHabicht Sorry. I hadn't refreshed my page and noticed your answer when I made the edit.

Comment: That's totally okay. Just keep yours as it is now.

Comment: @Dan just a small doubt, I want to add some padding before and after of the list, how do I  achieve it? {after using the 2nd approach that you mentioned}

Comment: @theSwapnilSaste Add `before={\hspace{2mm}}, after={\hspace{2mm}}` options to the `\setlist` line. You can replace `2mm` with whatever length you desire.

Answer (score 2):

```
\NewDocumentEnvironment{skilllist}{}
   {%
     \RenewDocumentCommand{\item}{m} % ❶
        {%
          #1%
          \RenewDocumentCommand{\item}{m} % ❷
            { \textpipe\ ##1}% ❸
        }%
   }
   {%
     \par % ❹
   }
```

In the `\begin{skilllist}` definition we redefine `\item` ❶ to take a single argument which will be your skill. And within that redefinition, we will redefine `\item` again ❷ so that after the first `\item` each item will have | printed to separate it from the preceding items (with spaces before and after the |). Note also the use of `##1` in the inner redefinition so that LaTeX knows that we're referring to the definition of the defined command and not an outer command.

I've done no other real formatting since you'll likely handle that on your own other than to end the paragraph ❹ in the `\end{skilllist}` definition, but you can obviously add whatever additional formatting is necessary (e.g., enclosing each skill in `\mbox` to prevent line breaks in the middle of a skill).

Comment: You can also use a delayed executing technique for the separator. See [Cunning (La)TeX tricks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89187/5764).