# How to Specify a Fixed Gap to Precede Each New Heading in the Index

Tags: indexing, imakeidx, makeindex, vertical-spacing, idxlayout

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\makeindex
%\usepackage[font=small]{idxlayout}
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\LARGE

Some words.\index{\textbf{HEADING1}! \textbf{\color{red}{Subheading}}! The entry immediately above HEADING2.}

Some words.\index{\textbf{HEADING2}! \textbf{\color{red}{Subheading}}! I would like to be able to globally specify the size of the gap between a new heading (such as HEADING2 and the last line of the entry immediately above it.}

\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

which produces the index

[image]

Observe how small the vertical space is that precedes HEADING2.

QUESTION: How may I increase the space between the last line of the index entry of HEADING1 and the display position of HEADING2? I would like to be able to specify the value of this gap for all subsequent headings as well.

Thank you.

Comment: How many of these **HEADING**s will you have?

Comment: @Werner The actual document has many headings; maybe 35 or thereabouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've implemented something else below that might be of interest to your setup - a key-valued approach to setting an `\index` entry `heading` and `subheading`. This removes the formatting specification from the end-user, allowing you to be a bit more consistent/uniform in your use headings/subheadings. That is, you don't have to specify the heading with `\textbf{<heading>}` every time. Instead,

```
\myindex[heading={<heading>},subheading={<subheading>}]{<index entry>}
```

would check whether you've supplied a `heading`/`subheading` and index the `<index entry>` accordingly.

Additionally, `\addvspace{<len>}` is added with every `heading` to ensure there's a sufficient gap up to `<len>` *above* the `heading` (except for the *first* heading which should sit right below the **Index** title; this can be changed).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex

\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{xkeyval}
\makeatletter
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\insertidxheadinggap}{}{%
  % Delayed execution of macro (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89187/5764)
  \def\insertidxheadinggap{\addvspace{\baselineskip}}}% Add \baselineskip above headings (excluding first)
\define@cmdkey{idx}{heading}[\relax]{}% Heading title
\define@cmdkey{idx}{subheading}[\relax]{}% Subheading title
\newcommand{\myindex}[2][]{%
  \setkeys{idx}{%
    heading,subheading,% Default settings
    #1}% User-provided settings
  % Construct \index{...} command based on heading/subheading supplied by user
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\index{%
      \expandafter\ifx\cmdKV@idx@heading\relax\else
        \cmdKV@idx@heading @%
        \insertidxheadinggap%
        \noexpand\textbf{\cmdKV@idx@heading}!% Heading format: \textbf{<heading>}
      \fi
      \expandafter\ifx\cmdKV@idx@subheading\relax\else
        \noexpand\textbf{\noexpand\color{red}\cmdKV@idx@subheading}!% Subheading format: \textbf{\color{red}<subheading}
      \fi
      #2% Index entry
  }}\x
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some words.%
\myindex[heading={Heading 1},subheading=Subheading]{The entry immediately above ``Heading 2.''}

Some words.%
\myindex[heading={Heading 2},subheading=Subheading]{I would like to be able to globally specify the size 
  of the gap between a new heading (such as ``Heading 2'' and the last line of the entry immediately above it).}

\myindex[heading={Heading 2},subheading={Another subheading}]{Something}
\myindex[heading={Heading 2}]{Somethine else}
\myindex[heading={Heading 2},subheading=Subheading]{Another entry}
\myindex[heading={Heading 321}]{Some other index entry}

\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex

\end{document}
```

The above approach assumes you'll have a bunch of headings and no non-heading entries, as they may not have the appropriate spacing adjustments. Additionally, one could extend this to include a "sort string" for the heading, which will allow you to manipulate the position of the heading within other headings.

Comment: Thank you for posting this very helpful answer.