# How to generate a table from a list

Tags: tables, etoolbox

I am attempting to build up a list of rows for a table, then render that list into a table. I'm using `etoolbox` to manage the list and loop over it. I'm close but I can't get more than one column of the table to generate correctly. It seems like after the first `&` the rest get lost.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document} 

\newcommand\mylist{}

\newcommand{\addRow}[3]{
  \listadd{\mylist}{#1,#2,#3}
}

\newcommand{\makerow}[1]{
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{##1&}
  \docsvlist{#1}
}

\newcommand{\dorow}[1]{\makerow{#1} \\ \hline}

\newcommand{\makeTable}{
  \begin{table}[H]
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
      \hline
      Uppercase & Number & Lowercase \\ \hline
      \forlistloop{\dorow}{\mylist}
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
}

\addRow{A}{1}{a}
\addRow{B}{2}{b}
\addRow{C}{3}{c}
\makeTable

\end{document}
```

[image: malformed table]

---

## Update 1

I made some progress debugging the table. I realized I was getting an extra `&` at the end of each row before `\\ \hline` and was able to fix it with this http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89187/5764.

```latex
\newcommand{\makerow}[1]{%
  \def\delim{\def\delim{ & }}%
  \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\delim##1}%
  \docsvlist{#1}%
}
```

If I escape the `&`'s then I get the following table which seems to have everything in the right place

[image: escaped ampersands]

but without the escaped `&`'s it still looks like the first table. It's still as if the `&`'s are getting dropped or not interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a more compact code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\addRow}{mmm}
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g__nelson_table_seq { {#1},{#2},{#3} }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\makeTable}{}
 {
  \begin{flushleft}
  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
  \hline
  Uppercase & Number & Lowercase \\ \hline
  \seq_map_function:NN \g__nelson_table_seq \__nelson_table_make:n
  \end{tabular}
  \end{flushleft}
 }

\seq_new:N \g__nelson_table_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__nelson_table_make:n
 {
  \clist_use:nn { #1 } { & } \\ \hline
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\addRow{A}{1}{a}
\addRow{B}{2}{b, q}
\addRow{C}{3}{c}
\makeTable

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\addRow` command adds, like in your code, a comma separated list to a global sequence (analog to the `etoolbox` list). When `\makeTable` is called, the sequence is mapped over, and each item does `\clist_use:nn { #1 } { & }`, that puts `&` between each item; at the end we issue `\\`.

Each item is protected inside braces, so a comma in an argument won't break (an example is shown).

Finally, there is no need for `\begin{table}[H]` and `flushleft` is sufficient (maybe you want `center` instead).

Comment: This is awesome, thank you. One weird thing is that I need to escape spaces in any text I put in the \makeTable or multi-word, column headings get squashed together. Any idea why?

Comment: @PhilipNelson If you need spaces in the headers, you need to denote them as `~`

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. (Added the missing `\delim`)

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document} 
    
    \newcommand\mylist{}
    
    \newcommand{\addRow}[3]{
    \def\delim{&}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \listadd{\mylist}{#1,\delim#2,#3}% changed <<<<<<<<<<<
    }
    

\newcommand{\makerow}[1]{%
    \def\delim{\def\delim{&}}%
    \renewcommand*{\do}[1]{##1\delim}%
    \docsvlist{#1}%
}
    
    \newcommand{\dorow}[1]{\makerow{#1} \\ \hline}
    
    \newcommand{\makeTable}{
        \begin{table}[H]
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
                \hline
                Uppercase & Number & Lowercase \\ \hline
                \forlistloop{\dorow}{\mylist}
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
    }
    
    \addRow{A}{1}{a}
    \addRow{B}{2}{b}
    \addRow{C}{3}{c}
    \addRow{D}{4}{d}
    
    \makeTable  

\end{document}
```